# How to printf uint64_t? Fails with: "spurious trailing ‘%’ in format"

Tags: c++, c

I wrote a very simple test code of printf uint64_t:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  uint64_t ui64 = 90;
  printf("test uint64_t : %" PRIu64 "\n", ui64);
  return 0;
}
```

I use ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit) and gcc version 4.6.1 to compile it, but failed:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:30: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRIu64’
main.cpp:9:47: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat]
```

Comment: It seems that you are compiling C code as C++, that is your error. If you rename your file to `main.c` and compile it with gcc, all should work fine.

Comment: Same without error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c

Comment: With either gcc or clang, it’s a good idea to specify `-std=c11` or the version of the standard you’re using. That catches this and other errors. I also recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion` at least.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The ISO C99 standard specifies that these macros must only be defined if explicitly requested.

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

... now PRIu64 will work
```

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. stackoverflow only allows me to accept the answer after a few minutes.   By the way, for other reader about lld and PRIu64, please visit: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml   item:64-bit Portability     Thanks you all again!

Comment: Hm, just including the header should suffice. The `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` macro is only required for inclusion in C++.

Comment: And this is actually the answer, Dan was just compiling his code with the wrong compiler.

Comment: or not -std=c99 or any other small detail

Comment: @Jens: Indeed; `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` appears only in a footnote in C99, suggesting that C++ only define these macros in the presence of the request.  However the C++ committee chose to ignore the suggestion: e.g. in the n3242 draft, 27.9.2/3: _Note: The macros defined by <cinttypes> are provided unconditionally. In particular, the symbol __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS, mentioned in footnote 182 of the C standard, plays no role in C++._  So when the compilers catch up, we won't need `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` in either C or C++.

Comment: @John Marshall g++ 4.7.3 seems to require the macro, even when <inttypes.h> is included.

Comment: @Eric: Apparently g++ 4.7.3 hadn't caught up!  In fact, probably you are using it with a glibc version that predates [this bug fix](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15366).  As discussed in that glibc report, your g++ 4.7.3's libstdc++ has code to work around this problem.  If you compile with `-std=c++0x` and perhaps #include <cinttypes> rather than <inttypes.h>, I believe it'd provide the format macros without you supplying `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS`.

Comment: Also works for PRIu32, just for keyword searching sake :)

Comment: ISO C99 doesn't specify anything about `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS`. It's only mentioned in a footnote (and that footnote was removed in C11).  In C99 and C11, `#include <inttypes.h>` must define the format macros.

Comment: @JohnMarshall It actually seems that the footnote still does apply to `<inttypes.h>`, but is overruled by the C++ standard for `<cinttypes>`, since the note in the C++ standard doesn't mention `<inttypes.h>`, only `<cinttypes>` (which doesn't exist with this name in C). I suppose you still do have to use `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS`, since the standard is not too clear — and may be interpreted differently by implementations.

Comment: @Ruslan: What footnote? As M.M noted, it's gone in C11 — `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` no longer appears in the C standard.  Agreed though that this probably remains a mess in implementations… Perhaps the glib answer to all this is that it's immaterial in C++: if you're using `<<` and `>>` you surely have no interest in these _inttypes_ macros that are only for use with `printf`/`scanf`.

Comment: @JohnMarshall I agree that they are almost useless in C++. I even learned about the mess only when I tried to compile a C++ library which used `inttypes.h` with `PRIxLEAST64` and didn't define this macro — which doesn't compile with my particular glibc version.

Comment: This answer should be edited to include the information from the comments below it. It seems very outdated.

Answer (score 4):

When compiling memcached under Centos 5.x i got the same problem.

The solution is to upgrade gcc and g++ to version 4.4 at least.

Make sure your CC/CXX is set (exported) to right binaries before compiling.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've included the C++ tag, you could use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) and avoid the `PRIu64` macro and other `printf` issues altogether:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  uint64_t ui64 = 90;
  fmt::print("test uint64_t : {}\n", ui64);
}
```

The formatting facility based on this library is proposed for standardization in C++20: [P0645](http://wg21.link/p0645).

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt}.

Comment: Cool! Is it coming also something similar to `sscanf`?

Comment: Quite possibly. We are investigating the possibility of replacing `scanf`.

Comment: Great! Also I wonder if there are progress towards a locale independent and/or locale selectable version of [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). The cppreference page still link only to [`std::to_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars), which is not really what people need. I wonder if `fmt` and/or c++20 deal with it or not yet.

Comment: `std::to_string` will probably remain as is, but `std::format` allows you to control whether to use locale or not (and by default it doesn't use the locale).