# Width of int64_t, is it always 64 bits?

Tags: c, gcc, x86

For the following code

```
static inline float fix2float(int64_t f)
{
    return (float)f / (1 << 60); // <-- error here
}
```

The compiler is giving me these warnings.

```
warning: left shift count >= width of type
warning: division by zero
```

Why is the compiler giving these warnings when 64 > 60?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`1` is not a 64-bit number in your C implementation. It is an `int`, which is likely 32 bits.

The compiler does not look over an expression and see that there is an `int64_t` involved, therefore other arithmetic should use 64 bits. It builds up expressions from their parts. In the part `(1 << 60)`, the compiler recognizes one and gives it a type of `int`, because that is what the C rules say to do with simple constant values (there are additional rules for hexadecimal notation, suffixes, and large values). So, `1 << 60` tries to shift an `int` by 60 bits. Since the `int` on your system is only 32 bits, the compiler warns you.

A better way to write this is `return f * 0x1p-60f;`. `0x1p-60f` is a `float` constant with value 2<sup>–60</sup>.

Comment: +1: I did not know that syntax for C99 hex exponents.... (that said, I don't think one should use this syntax without a _prominent_ code comment explaining the magic)

Comment: @NormanGray: It’s been a part of the language for *13 years*.  It’s hardly “magic".

Comment: It's C – _only_ 13 years means it counts as a novelty (remember, some folk still think that non-K&R C is a pretty rad idea). But seriously, this syntax is unique to C as far as I'm aware, and it's at least somewhat arcane, therefore a prominent comment would be civil to the code's eventual reader.

Answer (score 3):

In your code there is error not actually related to int64_t. In `(1 << 60)` expression both `1` and `60` are considered int (which is usually 32 bits). You should use modifier `LL`.
Something like (1LL << 60).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%llx\n", (1LL << 60));
    return 0;
}
```

By the way please pay attention to `printf()` format. `int64_t` is actually `long long` (at least in most cases).

UPDATE: there is community voice that recommends to use somewhat different approach:

```
printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", (UINT64_C(1) << 60));
```

The issue here is at least in my area not all compilers properly implement these macros (here is [one of possible proofs](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/685726/int64-c-and-uint64-c-should-be-defined-in-more-cross-platform-way)). But mainstream compilers should be happy. At least I'd not recommend to mix `%lld` and `1LL` even in GCC (you could try, at least GCC 4.6.3 complains about such mix).

Comment: In all cases, you can use [`"%" PRId64`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c) to format `int64_t`, no need to assume it's an alias for `long long`.

Comment: The proper way to write an `int64_t` constant with value 1 is `INT64_C(1)`, not `1LL`. The proper format specifier for it is `PRId64`, as in `printf("%" PRId64 "\n",…);`, after `#include <inttypes.h>`, of course. Also, `x` is for unsigned. If you want to print an `int64_t` with hexadecimal, you should convert it to `uint64_t` and print it with `PRIx64`.