# Is there a difference between these two implemenations?

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any difference on how the compiler will generate the code for the following two. Secondly, will they produce the same return values.

```
  static inline float fix2float(int64_t f)
  {
    return (float)f / ((int64_t)1 << 60); 
  }
```

and this

```
  static inline float fix2float(int64_t f)
  {
    return (float)(f / ((int64_t)1 << 60)); 
  }
```

Comment: You realize that you're still doing a 32 bit shifting ? (talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085107/width-of-int64-t-is-it-always-64-bits/16085183#16085183)

Comment: Note that `(int64_t)(1 << 60)` is probably not what you mean, and is very likely to not work. You need `(((int64_t) 1) << 60)` to make the `1` 64-bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two functions are very different: the second one performs integer division, while the first one does floating-point.

In particular, the return value of the second version is always going to be an integer in the range [-8, 7].

**Update:** Of course this is only true if you first correct [the typo that unwind caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085380/is-there-a-difference-between-these-two-implemenations#comment22963370_16085380).

Comment: True, but I think the range is [7, -8] since you have 4 bits left.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: 1 << 60 ones the 60th bit in the 0..63 range, so 3 bits left.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Dumb moment, "obviously" the 60th bit should also be counted among those that are "left". Thanks for the reminder, I fixed the range too.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is: in C, [typecast has higher precedence than division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), so the first one will divide in `float`, while the second one will perform an integer division.