# what is printf format specifier for cl_ulong

Tags: printf, opencl

@H2CO3

this is my main code :

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_ amd_ printf : enable
#define PROGRAM_FILE "matvec.cl"
#define KERNEL_FUNC "matvec_mult"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
int main() {
cl_platform_id platform;
cl_device_id device;
cl_context context;
cl_command_queue queue;
cl_int i,err;
cl_int length = 512;
cl_program program;
FILE *program_handle;
char *program_buffer;
size_t program_size;
cl_kernel kernel;
size_t work_units_per_kernel;
float mat_a[length], mat_b[length];
cl_mem mat_a_buff, mat_b_buff, res_buff;
cl_event timing_event;
cl_ulong time_start, time_end , read_time;

//********************************************************************
//           making matrix a & b

for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
mat_a[i] = i ;
mat_b[i] = i +1;
}
//********************************************************************

clGetPlatformIDs(2, &platform, NULL);
clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1 , &device, NULL);
context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL,NULL, &err);
program_handle = fopen(PROGRAM_FILE, "r");
fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
program_size = ftell(program_handle);
rewind(program_handle);
program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';

//*******************************************************************
// !!!!!!!!!   reading buffer  :    
fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size,program_handle);
//*******************************************************************   
fclose(program_handle);
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,(const char**)&program_buffer,&program_size,&err);
free(program_buffer);

clBuildProgram(program, 0 , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL);

// !!!    Creating & Queueing Kernel  :
//*********************************************************************************

kernel = clCreateKernel(program , KERNEL_FUNC , &err);
queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device , CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE , &err);

//*********************************************************************************
mat_a_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
sizeof(float)*4,  mat_a, &err);
mat_b_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
sizeof(float)*4 , mat_b, &err);
res_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,sizeof(float)*4, NULL, &err);

// !!!   Setting Kernel Arguments   :   


clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mat_a_buff);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mat_b_buff);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &res_buff);


work_units_per_kernel = 512;

//   !!!  Parallelism with clEnqueueNDRangekernel structure 
//**********************************************************************************************    
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL,&work_units_per_kernel,
NULL, 0, NULL, &timing_event);
//**********************************************************************************************    

//********************  Profilling :  *****************************

clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,
sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
read_time = time_end - time_start;
printf("The average time is :  %lu\n", read_time);                  
//********************************************************************************************* 
clReleaseMemObject(mat_a_buff);
clReleaseMemObject(mat_b_buff);
clReleaseMemObject(res_buff);
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseContext(context);
return 0;
}
```

but although the cl_ulong is the unsigned long , the printf with %lu flag does not act . this is the error code line :
(format %lu expects argument of type long unsigned int but argument 2 has type cl_ulong[-Wformat])

so i don't know what is the problem and why printf does't work properly ???

Answer (score 3):

On the cl_platform.h header installed on my machine, i found that cl_ulong is define as:

```
typedef uint64_t  cl_ulong;
```

So I guess you could try to printf as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c).

BTW, I don't know if you use the pragma for something else in your code, but the printf you are using here is the regular C one since it is the host side code. So no need for the pragma in this specific case. Moreover since OpenCL 1.2, the printf is part of the built-in functions making obsolete the extension from AMD and therefore the pragma statement.

Comment: hi, i do your advise but there is still the error message , and printf doesn't work !!!

Comment: Which advice? The one asking you to try the solution given in the link? What does it mean it doesn't work? What is the result?

Comment: hi , you are right, i know what you saied ,& tried the solution , but it still make the same error !!! i put the error message in the page again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326819/printf-makes-error-and-dont-show-the-result

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not guaranteed that `cl_ulong` *always* corresponds to host's `uint64_t`. So I think you should cast those values to a known type first before using in `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, OpenCL specification but doesn't define `printf` format specifiers for it's integer types, but it [actually prescribes](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html) `cl_ulong` to be 64-bit integer. This may not match with C type `unsigned long` which isn't forced by C standard to be that wide and may be just 32-bit. But `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to being able to hold 64-bit integer.

So, I'd suggest you to either:

- cast `cl_ulong` to `unsigned long long` and use `%llu`, or;
- cast `cl_ulong` to `uint64_t` and use `PRIo64` format specifier.

Bot `unsigned long long` and `uint64_t` were introduced by C99, so there're no major difference in portability. In both cases the conversion should be lossless and may only widen value.

Usage is as following:

```
printf("The average time is: %llu\n", (unsigned long long)read_time);
```

or following:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
printf("The average time is: %"PRIu64"\n", (uint64_t)read_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the nomenclature of OpenCL makes sense, then I'd expect `ulong` to be a typedef for `unsigned long`, hence the correct conversion specifier would be `%lu`.

Comment: hi , you are right , ulong is the type for unsigned long , but i dont know why %lu does't work !!! when i use fprint with this flag it make this error : (%lu is for unsigned long but you use ulong type in yor code), now what should i do ?

Comment: @mehdioraki Have a look at the typedef for `cl_ulong`. If it's not `unsigned long`, then its name is misleading, you should change the format specifier appropriately, and beat the writer of the library with a thick and heavy stick.

Comment: i put my code on the page , perhaps u can find the error , thank soo much

Answer (score 0):

If this is a 64bit type, try %lld (long long).

Answer (score 0):

As one of the other answers mentioned, the [sizes of OpenCL scalar data types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html) are a constant number of bits:

```
DATA TYPE            | BITS
===========================
cl_char  / cl_uchar  |    8
cl_short / cl_ushort |   16
cl_int   / cl_uint   |   32
cl_long  / cl_ulong  |   64
```

However, since you [can't assume the size of a `long`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35844670/477563) on a given system, using `%llu` or `%lu` would be **incorrect**.

---

That said, C and C++ have the [`inttypes.h` header](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html), which defines macros for printing fixed-sized integer values.
The *printing* macros are in the form **`PRI[format][size]`**:

- **`[format]`** is one of: `d` - signed, `u` - unsigned, `o` - octal, `x` - hex
- **`[size]`** is the integer size in bits (`8`, `16`, `32`, or `64`)

For example: `PRIu64` is used to print a 64-bit unsigned integer and `PRIx32` is used to print a 32-bit integer in hex.

**Note:** These macros only define the "specifier" section of a `printf` variable, not the `%` marker.
When you use them in a program, it needs to look like `printf("X = %" PRIu32 "\n", x);`

---

Putting the above together, we end up with the following:

```
DATA TYPE  | FORMAT
===================
cl_char    | PRId8
cl_uchar   | PRIu8
cl_short   | PRId16
cl_ushort  | PRIu16
cl_int     | PRId32
cl_uint    | PRIu32
cl_long    | PRId64
cl_ulong   | PRIu64
```

Of course, if you'd rather print the integer in octal you would use `o` instead of `d` or `u`.
Likewise, if you wanted the integer in hex, you would use `x` instead.

Comment: “However, since you can't assume the size of a long on a given system, using %llu or %lu would be incorrect.” — that's true that you cannot rely on `unsigned long` being at least 64 bits wide, but that's not so for `unsigned long long`. See [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section “5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>”.