# add two unsigned value in C and C#

Tags: c#, c, unsigned, ulong

I have a calculation in c that I should write it in c#

this is my code in c:

```
const unsigned long *S //which is an array that already contains data ) 
unsigned long  y;
y = y + S[d]; //S[d] = 2582066069 and y = 3372499074 and the results is 1659597847
```

but in my C# code:

```
ulong[] S = (ulong[])hashtable[key];
ulong y = 2582066069;
y = y + S[d]; // s[d] = 3372499074 but the result is = 5954565143
```

I don't undrestand the difference in this add operation in c and c#
would you pelase help me too undrestand where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the exact same example numbers in the two calculations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `C` case, the `unsigned long` data size is `4 bytes` while in `C#`, `ulong` data size is `8-bytes`.

```
unsigned long   4 bytes 0 to 4,294,967,295 //in C
ulong           8 bytes 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 //in C#
```

Thus in your `C` case, when you add the two values, you will get overflow.

```
3372499074 + 2582066069 = 5954565143 (overflow) = (4294967296 + 1659597847) mod 4294967296 = 1659597847
```

But in your `C#` case, the `ulong` data type is still able to hold the value without overflow.

```
3372499074 + 2582066069 = 5954565143 (no overflow)
```

Find out more of the data type value limit in [C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) and in [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/s3f49ktz.aspx). Also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844586/can-i-assume-the-size-of-long-int-is-always-4-bytes) for more understanding on `C` data type size ([dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush)'s and [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan)'s answers are particularly helpful. Since there isn't some standardized size for `long` data type in `C`, in may sometimes be `4 bytes` and sometimes `8 bytes` - unlike `C#`'s counterpart, `ulong` is always `8 bytes`)

To have a `8 bytes unsigned integer` data type in C, you could use `uint64_t` data type

```
uint64_t u64;
```

Comment: Correct, this is an C error, and C# is managed. You can not reproduce overflow like in C withing C#. You could use modulo (%) operator to recreate an equal behaviour for that exact scenario.

Comment: @Mafii That's not correct.  C# has the ability to check for overflow and throw an exception but that can be turned on or off at the compiler level or in the code with `checked` and `unchecked`.

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware about that. Is the code still called managed then?

Comment: @Mafii arithmetic overflow has nothing to do with it being a managed language.  Managed just means it takes care of allocation and de-allocation of memory for you.

Comment: "unsigned long data size is 4 bytes".. well not always, but in this case could be.

Comment: `uint64_t` will be better than `unsigned long long`