# Size of int data type in 16 bit vs 32 bit machine in C

Tags: c, primitive-types

Why the size of **int** data type is different in **16 bit** and **32 bit** architectures while the **other primitive data types** have same size in both architectures?

Comment: The sizes of all the predefined integer types are implementation-defined. What specific implementations are you asking about?

Comment: The standard guarantees some minimum sizes for things, but as far as I know `char` is the only type with a guaranteed upper bound.

Comment: who told you that "other primitive data types have same size in both architectures"? lots of architectures have [32 or 64-bit `long`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35844586/995714). Many may have [8, 9, 16, 24 or 32-bit `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/995714). The C standard doesn't mandate a fixed size for any types

Comment: @MadPhysicist `char` has no upper bound.  Problems do ensue when range of `char` == range of `int`.

Comment: @chux. I was not aware of that. I thought char was always guaranteed to be a single byte.

Comment: @MadPhysicist In C, a `char` is always a single byte (as C defines a byte).  Sometimes that byte is 8 bits, sometimes more.

Comment: @chux. Sure, the number of bits is not fixed, but there is a cap in bytes and int is always guaranteed to be bigger.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Look forward to your reference to support  "there is a cap and int is always guaranteed to be bigger (than char)".

Comment: Unisys Clear Path systems have 9-bit chars, 36-bit ints and 72-bit long long int, and 1's complement representation.

Comment: @mad Perhaps [Can sizeof(int) ever be 1 on a hosted implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861506/2410359)

Comment: @KeithThompson..implementations regarding compiler?well mine is a GNU GCC compiler

Answer (score 6):

The sizes of the common garden-variety integral types (`int`, `long`, `short`, etc) are not fixed by the C standard, the only requirement is that they have minimum capacities and that their relative sizes follows an equal-or-better rule (e.g., `long` is *at least* as large as `int`).

This is because (1) the original implementations simply used the most natural size for the architecture; and (2) the original mandate of the standardisation committee was to codify *existing* practice, not invent a *new* language.

If you *want* fixed-sized integral types, use the `intN_t` style ones, such as `int16_t` or `uint32_t`. These were introduced for exactly that purpose.

Comment: _equal-or-better_ -- implying bigger is better. I see how it is~ **Edit** Upvoted when you finally answered the "why".