# how do I solve this C++ access violation problem?

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error in the following code.  Visual Studio throws an access violation error when writing to `_buf`.  How can I fix this?

The `Sendn` function is a socket sending function.  It's not the problem, you can ignore it.

It looks like `_buf` points at `0x00000000`

The error message I'm seeing is

> ```
> 0xC0000005: 0x00000000 : access violation
> ```

```
void ?????::?????(int number, string title)
{

    int titlesize = sizeof(title);
    int bufsize = 4 + 4 + 4 + titlesize;

    char *_buf = new char[bufsize];

    _buf = { 0 };

    // char _buf[bufsize] = { 0 }; (수정 내용)

    int commands = 3;

    int index = 0;
    memcpy(_buf, &commands, sizeof(int));
    index += sizeof(int);

    memcpy(_buf + index, &number, sizeof(int));
    index += sizeof(int);

    memcpy(_buf + index, &titlesize, sizeof(int));
    index += sizeof(int);
    for (int i = 0; i < titlesize; i++)
    {
        memcpy(_buf + index, &title[i], sizeof(char));
        index += sizeof(char);
    }

    Sendn(_buf, bufsize);

    delete[] _buf;

    return;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you are `memcpy()`-ing the `title`, one character at a time, with its own dedicated `for` loop, instead of simply `memcpy()`ing the whole thing, in one shot?

Comment: Side note, while I think it's not an issue here, as a general rule, [starting symbol names with an underscore is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) because if not done right, it can lead to using some reserved identifiers by accident.

Comment: Other side note: instead of `int bufsize = 4 + 4 + 4 + titlesize;`, you should probably do something like `int bufsize = sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + titlesize;`, since [`int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35844670/10957435).

Comment: I recommend using [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) rather than [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) as it is safer and just as fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *_buf = new char[bufsize];
_buf = { 0 };
```

This does not zero-fill the dynamically-allocated array pointed to by `_buf`.  It sets the pointer `_buf` to be a null pointer.  Since `_buf` is a null pointer, later attempts to dereference it lead to undefined behavior.

There's no need to zero-fill the array pointed to by `_buf` in this case, so you can simply remove the `_buf = { 0 };` line.

---

Once you've fixed that problem, you also aren't allocating the right amount of memory.  `sizeof(title)` will not give you the number of characters that `title` holds.  It just gives you the static size of a `std::string` object, which is usually only a pointer and two integers.  Use `title.size()` instead.

Comment: Fun fact, [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) will fill an array like this, however.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to copy the content of `title` together with 3 other integer numbers into `_buf` right? The problem is that `sizeof(title)` is not the length of the string stored in `title`. In order to get the length of `title`, you need to call the member function `length` on type `std::string` like this:

```cpp
auto titlesize = title.length();
```

The `sizeof` operator only gives you the size of your `std::string` object on stack (in comparison, the actual string is stored on heap) and `sizeof` expressions are always constant expressions. On my computer, `sizeof(std::string)` is 24 regardless of what the actual string is.

Comment: `std::string::length` and `std::string::size` behave exactly the same, by the way.