# Returned uint64_t seems truncated

Tags: c, 64-bit, return-type, uint64

I would like to return a `uint64_t` but the result seems truncated:

In `lib.c`:

```
uint64_t function()
{
    uint64_t timestamp = 1422028920000;
    return timestamp;
}
```

In `main.c`:

```
uint64_t result = function();
printf("%llu  =  %llu\n", result, function());
```

The result:

```
394745024  =  394745024
```

At compilation, I get a warning:

```
warning: format '%llu' expects argument of type 'long long unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'uint64_t' [-Wformat]
warning: format '%llu' expects argument of type 'long long unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
```

Why is the compiler thinking that the return type of my function is an `int`? How can we explain that the reslut printed is different from the value sent by the function `function()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c

Comment: Have you created a header file that declares the functions in your lib.c file ? And did you include that header file in main.c ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, the `#include <stdint.h> is used in both files. Furthermore, to answer unwind, the file `lib.c` is the implementation of a `lib.h`

Comment: @Jav: He's not talking about `#define <stdint.h>` (though that's incorrect anyways --- I assume you mean `#include`), he's talking about declaring `function` in a header, and then including it in `main.c`.

Comment: @TimČas indeed : *include

Comment: OKay -_- ... I had not included the `lib.h`

Comment: @Jav: Had you enabled compiler warnings, the compiler would've told you about that. I'd recommend using `-Wall`, myself (assuming you're using GCC or CLang; I don't know what other compilers use).

Comment: stupid mistake. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct, the value is being truncated to 32 bits.

It's easiest to verify by looking at the two values in hex:

```
1422028920000 = 0x14B178754C0
    394745024 =    0x178754C0
```

So clearly you're getting the least significant 32 bits.

To figure out why: are you declaring `function()` properly with a prototype? If not, compiler will use the implicit return type of `int` that explains truncation (you have 32-bit `int`s).

In `main.c`, you should have something like:

```
uint64_t function(void);
```

Of course if you have a header for your `lib.c` file (say, `lib.h`), you should just do:

```
#include "lib.h"
```

instead.

Also, don't use `%llu`. Use the proper one, which is given by the macro `PRIu64`, like so:

```
printf("%" PRIu64 " = %" PRIu64 "\n", result, function());
```

These macros were added in C99 standard and are located in the `<inttypes.h>` header.

Comment: tell the OP what print format to use - how to find it.  Or at least link.  ...good you beat me to it. +1

Comment: You have an error there --- `PRIi64` instead of `PRIu64` for `function()`.

Comment: @TimČas What? Isn't `PRIu64` correct for printing an unsigned value?

Comment: @unwind: Yes, but you use both: `PRIu64` for `result` (correct), but `PRIi64` for `function` (incorrect).

Comment: @unwind, the problem was actually that I forgot to add the `#include <lib.h>` And this doesn't not appear in your answer

Comment: @Jav That depends ... but I edited to make it even more clear. Enjoy.