# Why can't I use "long long int" with "int" in my C code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

Why can't I use "long long int" with "int" in my C code?

```
int main(void) {
    long long int a;
    int b;
    a = 1000000000;
    b = 3200;
    printf("long long int a = %d\n int b = %d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

> long long int a = 1000000000
>
> int b = 0

Comment: %d refers to a regular int, not a long long.

Comment: Hmm I think VS might using a different specifier.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c

Comment: Voting to close as "simple typographic error" as the answer is likely found in chapter 1 of most C programming books.

Comment: `printf` is a vararg function (`..` -> variable arguments). It'll use the format specifiers to interpret/make sense of the arguments you pass to it. If you specify `%d`, but pass a `long long int`, the result will be _undefined behavior_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the correct format specifier in the printf function

```
printf("long long int a = %lld\n int b = %d", a, b);
```

Otherwise the function behaviour is undefined.

It seems that in the given situation the function considers the value of the long long int object pushed on the stack of the function as an argument like two objects of type int.

Comment: I had to stop counting how many dupes there are for this **specific**, **exact** same question, because I got an integer overflow from counting them!

Comment: @Rizier123 use `long long` to count them.

Comment: @Rizier123 If you find a good duplicate, please post a comment (to the question) with the link, and we can close it as a dupe straight away.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
printf("long long int a = %lld\n int b = %d", a, b);
```

`%d` is used to refer `int`. If you want to refer `long long int` then you have to use `%lld`

Answer (score 2):

Using wrong format specifier leads to undefined behavior the right format specifier to print out a `long long int` is `%lld`

Answer (score 1):

C99 standard says：
**If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**
The type of `a` is `long long int` but you use `%d` to print it.

Comment: Does visual-studio-2012 follow C99?

Comment: @chux Partly...I only want to say when we code we should try to avoid something that may cause error.

Comment: @chux Visual Studio doesn't follow any standard, least of all the C standards. To even call it a C compiler is questionable.

Comment: @Lundin OP tagged this post `visual-studio-2012` so answers should reflect that.  Discussing C99 without addressing OP's version of code is less helpful.

Comment: @Lundin: VS _does_ have a C89 compliant compiler, but they never bothered to implement the C99 standard. VS _does_ implement some C99 features (variadic macro's, `long long`) as a superset of C89, but they did not implement VLA's and the like

Comment: @chux Yes but it is also tagged C, making the tags contradict each other. Referring to C99 in a C post is perfectly fine, as it is probably the most used C standard still.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It contains so many oddities though, I very much doubt it is a strictly conforming compiler even by C90 standards.

Comment: @Lundin: As always, MS has added some _"features"_ and _"safer alternatives"_ throughout, but AFAIK, it is (theoretically) possible to compile standard C89 using VS (although, It'd probably be a lot easier, faster, and all-round better to just use a different compiler :-P)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons.

- Firstly and most importantly, I see no evidence of your compiler and/or standard library supporting C99, and hence no evidence of your compiler and/or standard library supporting `long long int` and the corresponding format specifier `%lld`.
- Secondly, you're lying to `printf` about the type of `a`; `%d` tells `printf` that the argument is of type `int`, even though it isn't (it's `long long int`). You should be using `%lld`...

Technically both of these would invoke undefined behaviour; using `%d` when your argument isn't an `int` is UB and even if you were to correctly use `%lld` you'd be using an invalid format specifier in C89's `scanf` (`%lld` is a C99 format specifier) and invoking UB as a result.

Have you considered using [Clang in Visual Studio](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html)?