# Printf types uintXX_t non working on a VM

Tags: c, printf, virtual-machine, string-formatting

I am running OpenSuse on Oracle Virtual Machine and I get this kind of error when I compiled my code :vir

`warning: format '%lx' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument has type 'uint64_t'`
Casting value did not help.

The code runs and compiles great on another OpenSuse laptop, I know that OS on virtual machine doesn't have the exact same behavior of 'normal boot' OS, but do you know which fix I can do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c. Not sure where `u_int64_t` is from, but it probably has the same representation as `uint64_t`.

Comment: It's probably a "bitness" problem of the guest OS, i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit. Virtual machines get no special treatment from the compiler.

Comment: Sorry I use a wrong name, I edited  my question. I will look at your link, thank you.

Comment: You should use a correct [format macro constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants), in your case `PRIx64`. See an [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Example) on how to use those macros.

Comment: I'm not sure : I use SCNx64 format for sscanf and I get these errors too. 

@HristoIliev My code originally run on 64 bits, and now the VM is on 32 bits, so that's should be it does not work.

I avoid errors printf errors  by casting with (long), but I still have sscanf errors. 
'sscanf(string,"%4" SCNx16, &uint16_t_value)'

Comment: The problem is you are assuming `long unsigned int` to be the same type as `uint64_t`, but that's not true on 32-bit Unix systems where the 64-bit integer type is `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

As per section `7.8 Format conversion of integer types <inttypes.h>` of the ISO (C11) standard, there are *specific* format specifiers for the specific-width-integer types defined in `stdint.h` (such as `uint64_t`):

> The header `<inttypes.h>` includes the header `<stdint.h>` and extends it with
>   additional facilities provided by hosted implementations.

A little further on from that, in `7.8.1 Macros for format specifiers`, it starts detailing the format specifiers you should use.

For the `uint64_t` type, the lower case hex output format is `PRIx64`, so you should be using something like:

```
printf ("The value is %" PRIx64 "\n", myUint64tVariable);
```