# How to printf a 64-bit integer as hex?

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit

With the following code I am trying to output the value of a `unit64_t` variable using `printf()`. Compiling the code with gcc, returns the following warning:

> warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’,
>   but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t’ [-Wformat=]

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main ()
{
    uint64_t val = 0x1234567890abcdef;
    printf("val = 0x%x\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
val = 0x90abcdef
```

Expected output:

```
val = 0x1234567890abcdef
```

How can I output a 64bit value as a hexadecimal integer using `printf()`? The `x` specifier seems to be wrong in this case.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c/9225648#9225648). basically, use the `PRIx64` macro from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: Use `printf("val = %#018"PRIx64"\n", val);` to print leading zeros. Don't forget to `#include <inttypes.h>`.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The warning from your compiler is telling you that your format specifier doesn't match the data type you're passing to it.

Try using `%lx` or `%llx`. For more portability, include `inttypes.h` and use the `PRIx64` macro.

For example: `printf("val = 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", val);` (note that it's string concatenation)

Comment: also `%016llx` could be used to ensure output has `padding` with zero (at the beginning) to reach `minimum field width` of `16` characters

Comment: Why does `0000000000000000` not get a `0x` at the front?

Comment: For the record, `PRIx64` is `#define`d to `"ll" "x"`

Comment: @Welgriv on which platform and compiler though? There's no guarantee that the macro will be defined to `"ll" "x"` on all platforms, and that's the whole point of the macro.

Comment: Yes, but `inttypes.h` looks the same in any platform. At least I have the same on Win10 (MINGW), Linux (gcc) and embed environment too (armcc).

Comment: @Welgriv I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. I don't doubt that many popular, modern platforms share the same definition of `PRIx64`.

Comment: @Welgriv It is certainly a mistake to assume that this is necessarily true on "any platform", though. I'm sure there's a counterexample out there, if one looks hard enough. Whether this is a real problem in practice is a different matter, however.

Comment: `PRIX64` also works, and prints uppercase rather than lowercase letters (A-F).

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

Edit: **Use `printf("val = 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", val);`** instead.

Try `printf("val = 0x%llx\n", val);`. See the [printf manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> ll (ell-ell). A following integer conversion corresponds to a long long int or unsigned long long int argument, or a following n conversion corresponds to a pointer to a long long int argument.

Edit: Even better is what @M_Oehm wrote: There is a specific macro for that, because `unit64_t` is not always a `unsigned long long`: `PRIx64` see also [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c/9225648#9225648)

Comment: I don't believe your edit is correct - it's not "%PRIx64" - it's a string concat with the value defined by the macro PRIx64

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison You were right, fixed it