# long int argument != long int parameter

Tags: c, int, printf, long-integer

When passing 1113355579999 as an argument, the value changes inside the function to 959050335.

Call(main.c):

```
printf("%d\n", FindCommonDigit(1113355579999, 123457));
```

Function(ex4.c):

```
int FindCommonDigit(long int n1, long int n2) { printf("%d\n", n1); }
```

What's the problem?
worth mentioning that the value changes before getting to the `printf`.

Comment: What is the result of `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(long int));` on your platform?

Comment: Did you enable warnings?

Comment: Also worth noting that `printf("%d\n", n1);` is wrong if `n1` is a `long int`.

Comment: The result of this is 4.

Comment: Use `long long int` and `%lld` as format specifier.

Comment: Warning is enabled, no alerts.

Comment: `long long int` just prints out another random number that isn't the argument.

Comment: @ArielGliksberg not reproducible https://ideone.com/FONQc5

Comment: Add `#include <limits.h>`, and then `printf("Maximum long value: %ld\n", LONG_MAX);` to see what your specific implementation of the C language supports for a `long int`.

Comment: Any compiler worth using should at least warn about the incorrect format specifier (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38561/3650362) for how to print a `long`). If you're on some special embedded platform where the only available C compiler is crappy enough not to warn, please name the compiler and the platform so we can help you better.

Comment: (If you're using gcc or clang, the flags to pass are `-Wall -Wextra`.)

Comment: Do you have a prototype for `FindCommonDigit()` in scope at the call statement? If you have not, the compiler will convert the value to `int`.

Comment: If code does not require integers, use `double`.  Most implementations can encode a 41 bit value like 1113355579999 exactly as a `double`.

Comment: Don't encode it as a double.  For one thing, your constant is 44-bits long.  For another, there are portable ways to guarantee you're getting 64-bit integers (see the answers below (and some of their comments))

Answer (score 6):

The decimal number 1113355579999 is too large to be accommodated by a 32-bit integer, which is a common size for type `long int`, and in fact [is the size of `long long int` in your MSVC environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).  On a C implementation that provides 32-bit `long int`s, that constant has type `long long int`.

You can pass a `long long int` to a parameter of type `long int`, but if the value is too large for `long int` then the resulting behavior is implementation-defined.  Possibly the least-significant 32 bits are retained, which, in the case of your particular number, would result in the number 959050335 (look familiar?).  To pass the argument into the function without loss of fidelity, the function parameter must have a type that can accommodate the argument.  On a conforming C implementation, `long long int` will suffice.

Having received the argument correctly, the function must also present it correctly to `printf()`, else the behavior is undefined.  The formatting directive for a `long long int` expressed in decimal is `%lld`.

Putting that together, you appear to want this:

```
int FindCommonDigit(long long int n1, long long int n2) {
    printf("%lld\n", n1);

    return /* ... something ... */;
}
```

You *do* need the function to return an `int`, else the behavior is again undefined.

Additionally, as @pmg observed in comments, a prototype for that function must be in scope at the point where it is called.  That would be this ...

```
int FindCommonDigit(long long int n1, long long int n2);
```

... near the top of the source file in which the function is used (i.e. `main.c`).  You can put that directly into the file if you like, but you should consider instead putting the prototype into a header file and `#include`ing that.  The latter is particularly useful if the function will be used in multiple source files.

Answer (score 2):

Note that only `long long int` is guaranteed to be large enough to store the result of that calculation (or, indeed, the input values you're using).

You will also need to ensure that you use your compiler in a C99-compatible mode (for example, using the `-std=gnu99` option to gcc).  This is because the `long long int` type was not introduced until C99

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, how can I ensure that my C99 compiler is in fact performing?

Comment: Unfortunately, older Visual C is mostly a C89 compiler, with a few C99 features added, and a few non-standard features as well; it looks like this has improved since MSVC2015, though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: So essentially the problem is in my compiler? C99 is needed?

Comment: Well, the problem is the mismatch between the assumptions and the implementation.  If you need 64-bit integers, check whether you have <stdint.h> (Visual Studio 2010 and later have it).  In that header are defined uint64_t and various other guaranteed-size types.  Note that there are special macros for printing the types from `stdint.h`, though.  Google how to use "PRIx64" or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112497/how-to-printf-a-64-bit-integer-as-hex for examples.

Comment: @ArielGliksberg, although MSVC2015 does not provide a fully-conforming C99 (nor even C89) compiler, I'm pretty sure it does have large enough `long long int`.  I'm not a big fan of Visual Studio's C compiler, but I don't think it's the cause of your particular problem.

Comment: Indeed.  In fact, the lack of compiler warnings makes me suspect that `long int` is actually 64-bit for his compiler, and the entire issue stems from using the `"%d"` format specifier, rather than `"%ld"`.  To make the code portable, though, `<stdint.h>` is the way to go.

Comment: On the contrary, @lockcmpxchg8b, [`long int` is 32 bits on MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).  The nature of the OP's problem (only the 32 least-significant bits are conveyed to the function via a `long int` parameter) strongly suggests this, too.  I attribute the lack of a warning to (1) MSVC's `int` and `long int` having the same size and representation, and (2, speculative) use of the default warning level.

Comment: It would be useful to include that info in your answer above.  In particular "32-bits being a common size" could give that link and indicate that it is in fact true for the OP.

Answer (score -1):

1113355579999 is too large to fit in your platform's long ints.

Comment: What does it mean _"your platform"_ and what can I do with it?

Comment: Your platform is your computer, your operating system and your compiler, with the libraries. If you are using Visual Studio, long long int should be large enough.