# %X format specifier prints value only up to 4 bytes?

Tags: c++, printf, format-specifiers

Hex value of 6378624653 is : 0x17C32168D
But this code prints : 0x7C32168D

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 6378624653;
    printf("0x%x", x);
}
```

can anyone explain why this happens ? and what should I do to get the right output?

Comment: What is the size of an int on your platform?

Comment: Change to `int x{ 6378624653 };`.  Then you can see the compiler error.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`

Comment: `long long x = 6378624653; printf("0x%llx", x);`

Comment: You must have compiler warnings disabled.  Turn them on!  Your compiler [wants to tell you about these problems](https://godbolt.org/z/avcvrK6s6).

Comment: You're using the wrong type for the `%x` format anyways. `%x` corresponds to `unsigned int` not to `int`. Why do you use `printf` instead of `std::cout` anyways? The latter would automatically apply the correct conversion. Furhtermore for `printf` you should include `cstdio`, not `iostream`...

Comment: @Wyck its working now, thanks and can you please explain the logic behind it?

Comment: @SouravSangral, See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112497/how-to-printf-a-64-bit-integer-as-hex  The largest number you can store in a 32-bit int is 0xFFFFFFFF.  Your number is bigger than that, so the next logical choice is 64-bit (long long).  After you get the right data stored in `x`, then you need to specify to printf that the value you're passing is 64-bits using a ___length sub-specifier___ which is the `ll` in `%llx` instead of just `%x` [see docs](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obtained result means that an object of the type `int` can not store such a big value as `6378624653`.

Try the following test program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << 6378624653 << '\n';
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() << '\n';
}
```

and see what the maximum value that can be stored in an object of the type `int`. In most cases using different compilers you will get the following output

```
2147483647
6378624653
4294967295
```

That is even objects of the type `unsigned int` can not store such value as 6378624653.

You should declare the variable `x` as having the type `unsigned long long int`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() 
{
    unsigned long long int x = 6378624653;
    printf( "%#llx\n", x );
}
```

The program output is

```
0x17c32168d
```