# How to extract a long unsigned int from a string literal using sscanf

Tags: c, long-integer, scanf

I tried using all these flags `ld` `li` and `lu` with `sscanf` but none worked. The following gets `4294967295` no matter what number i put in `buf`:

```
long unsigned data;
char buf[40] = "data 2349872764943587";

if (sscanf (buf, "data %lu", &data) == 1)
{
    printf ("%s\n", buf);
    printf ("data:\t%lu\n", data);
}
```

Output:

```
data 2349872764943587
data:   4294967295
```

Am I using the wrong conversion flag or is there something I missed?

Comment: use `long long unsigned`

Comment: Mind that a long unsigned int is a 32 bit data type, with the maximum of 4294967295?

Comment: check `sizeof(unsigned long)`. maybe you need `unsigned long long.`

Comment: My guess is that `long`s are only 32 bits on your platform. Use `uint64_t` instead to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: The size of `long` depends on compiler and platform. On e.g. Windows 64-bit using the Visual Studio compiler `long` is *still* 32 bits. You should use `unsigned long long` (or `uint64_t`) and corresponding formats (for which you could see e.g. [this `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) or [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)).

Comment: @Magisch: That is not necessarily true. E.g. POSIX64 is LP64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's `unsigned long` appears to be a 32-bit and so cannot represent the 51-bit `2349872764943587`.

If stuck using a compiler that lacks 64-bit integers, code could use `double`, which typically handles 53-bit whole number values without loss of precision.

```
double data;
char buf[40] = "data 2349872764943587";

if (sscanf (buf, "data %lf", &data) == 1)
{
    printf ("%s\n", buf);
    printf ("data:\t%.0f\n", data);
}
```

Output

```
data:   2349872764943587
```

Comment: printf complains about `ISO C90 does not support the '%lf' gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]`, however it works when i replace the `%0.lf` with `%0.f`. thanks :)

Comment: @razzak Yes - older compiler do not accept the `l` in printf formats.  Newer compilers (C99) simply allow it and ignore it. Answer amended.

Answer (score 1):

Your data type `long unsigned` is only guaranteed to be 32 bits in size, so the max value it can hold is `4294967295`, which you are getting.

Use a `unsigned long long` instead.

Comment: It's saying `error: ISO C90 does not support long long`

Comment: @razzak why are you compiling under ISO C90 standard? try the compiler option, `-std=c99` to compile under a standard that supports this.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, in your case, `unsigned long` occupies 4 bytes hence is not able to hold `2349872764943587` which takes more that 32 bits to be stored.

You can use `unsigned long long` (check the size using `sizeof`, need to be 8) or `uint64_t` instead.

Comment: It's saying `error: ISO C90 does not support long long`

Comment: @razzak use `-std=c99` option.

Comment: @razzak or, `-std=c11`, on gcc 4.7 and above.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Is there no way i can do this in C90?

Comment: @razzak remove `-pedantic` option. or you write library for unsigned 64bit. or use 8byte size unsigned long compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For portability, [avoid using](https://matt.sh/howto-c) `int`, `long`, etc. In your platform, for example, `long unsigned int` is 32 bits, which is why you have your problem.

Instead, `#include <stdint.h>` then use standard types, such as `int32_t`, `int64_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`. In your particular case, `uint64_t` does the trick.

To use `uint64_t data;` in `printf` and `scanf`, you need to `#include <inttypes.h>` and then `printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", data);`

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c).

Comment: `SCNu64` for `scanf`

Comment: @BlueMoon93 It complains about `ISO C90 does not support the 'll' gnu_scanf length modifier [-Wformat=]` and `ISO C90 does not support the 'll' gnu_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]`

Comment: @razzak On your compiler options, you need to use the `-std=c99` option