# Is this a bug in LLVM?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, sizeof

I am compiling this code (using clang 3.4.2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct __entry {
    char *name;
    int value;
} entry;

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
            printf("Size of entry: %lu\n", sizeof(entry));
        entry *entry = malloc(sizeof(entry));
        printf("entry is at %lu\n", (uint64_t) entry);
}
```

and I receive this bitcode:

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argv, i8** %argc) #0 {
entry:
  %argv.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %argc.addr = alloca i8**, align 8
  %entry1 = alloca %struct.__entry*, align 8
  store i32 %argv, i32* %argv.addr, align 4
  store i8** %argc, i8*** %argc.addr, align 8
  %call = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([20 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i64 16)
  %call2 = call noalias i8* @malloc(i64 8) #3
  %0 = bitcast i8* %call2 to %struct.__entry*
  store %struct.__entry* %0, %struct.__entry** %entry1, align 8
  %1 = load %struct.__entry** %entry1, align 8
  %2 = ptrtoint %struct.__entry* %1 to i64
  %call3 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([17 x i8]* @.str1, i32 0, i32 0), i64 %2)
  ret i32 0
}
```

The call to printf receives 16 as an argument (which I expected for a struct with two pointers on a 64-bit system). However, the call to malloc receives 8. In C, they both got the same argument. What is going on?

Comment: Does the program print the right values when run?

Comment: Your code invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: The bug is overloading the `entry` identifier for both a type and an object.

Comment: [using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714). You need to use [`%zu` to print size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714), and [`PRIu64` to print `uint64_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9225567/995714)

Comment: "Is this a bug in LLVM?" - Without reading the rest, I assure you: it is not! You might want to think about it.

Comment: The code as written is not portable because it doesn't use `PRIu64`, but it might be using the correct conversion specifier for the platform.

Comment: `%lu` is not the correct conversion type specifier for `size_t`, nor is it correct for `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two invocations of `sizeof` didn't get the same argument!  It only looked like they did at first glance.

The first `sizeof(entry)` refers to the type name.

The second `sizeof(entry)` refers to the local pointer variable.

After the variable is defined, you can no longer refer to the type in the block of code.

And this means that the answer to the headline question is "No — LLVM is following the requirements of the standard".

One minor quirk: the first `sizeof(entry)` must have the parentheses because the argument is a type name.  The second `sizeof(entry)` can be written `sizeof entry` because this argument is the name of a variable not a type.  This allows you to confirm that the second occurrence is referring to the variable and not the type.