# int64_t in printf function borland c++ builder 6

Tags: c, borland-c++

How to print int64_t type variable in function printf(). I use Borland C++ Builder 6.0, but I write small application in C. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This may help, it seems like  an identical question except it's for C. printf is a C function so I'm not sure if this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c

Comment: I would suggest something which is less than 16 years old

Comment: Answers to the other question say to use `%I64d` or `%lld`, but C++Builder actually uses `%Ld` for its int64 support in `printf()` (and `scanf()`). See [Embarcadero's documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Printf_Format_Specifiers)