# Strange behaviour of 64 bit integer in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, int64

I'm quite new to programming, I have recently learnt a little C++ and I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community version.

I need to use a 64 bit integer to store a value and carry out some arithmetic operations, however my compiler only allows me to use 32 bits of the "int64" variable I have created.

Here is an example of some code and the behaviour

```
    unsigned __int64  testInt = 0x0123456789ABCDEF;

printf("int value = %016X\n", testInt); // only 32 bits are being stored here? (4 bytes)

printf("size of integer in bytes = %i\n\n", sizeof(testInt)); // size of int is correct (8 bytes)
```

The value stored in the variable seems to be 0x0000000089ABCDEF.
Why can I not use all 64 bits of this integer, it seems to act as a 32 bit int?

Probably I'm missing something basic, but I can't find anything relating to this from searching :(

Comment: You need to use `%016llX` instead of `%016X`. The `%X` expects a 32-bit integer.

Comment: The `%X` format assumes a stock-standard `unsigned` (which may not be 64-bit), not a `unsigned __int64`.   From memory, an `unsigned` in VS2017 is 32-bit.   You need to use `ll` prefix to get `long long unsigned`

Comment: There are 64-bit specific format specifiers defined in <inttypes.h>. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225648/925478

Comment: Use a debugger to determine the actual contents of a variable.

Comment: @Reggie I'm glad it worked, but for future reference, it's is very much advisable to learn to write portable code, which means dealing with the macros and `"%016" PRIX64`

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if it were just something basic, but it turns out that 64 bit ints are not dealt with consistently on all platforms so we have to lean on macros.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225648/925478) describes the use of `PRIu64`, `PRIx64`, and related macros included in `<inttypes.h>`. It looks funny like this, but I think the portable solution would look like:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
unsigned __int64  testInt = 0x0123456789ABCDEF;
printf("int value = %016" PRIX64 "\n", testInt);
```

The `PRIX64` expands to the appropriate format specifier depending on your platform (probably `llX` for Visual Studio).

Comment: `PRIX64`, not `PRIx64` - OP's original code wants uppercase-hex output.  According to the link in that answer, the two macros are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Format specifier `%X` takes an unsigned int (probably 32 bit on your system), whereas `__int64` corresponds to `long long`.

Use `printf("int value = %016llX\n", testInt)` instead. Documentation can be found, for example, at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: For maximum portability (so, to write portable C++ rather than Visual C++ for x86_64), would it not be best to use `printf("int value = %016" PRIX64 "\n", testInt)` per @MykWillis's link?

Comment: @Darael: probably yes; though I suppose that `unsigned __int64` is not portable as well...