# Platform independent printf format for GLuint64?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a "facade" design pattern for OpenGL calls, which route the calls to their corresponding OpenGL call. I can additionally (but optionally) print out all OpenGL calls and their parameter values, which is useful for debugging. However, for methods which take a `GLuint64` parameter (such as [`glClientWaitSync`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClientWaitSync.xhtml)), I'm unsure which `printf` formatting to use. I'm specifically targeting Windows with MSVC and Linux with GCC and clang.

- `%lld` works with MSVC, but produces warnings with GCC/clang. (`warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 6 has type ‘GLuint64 {aka long unsigned int}`)
- `%lu` works with GCC/clang (in x64_86), but and doesn't cause warnings on MSVC. However, it doesn't print correctly (interpreted as a 32-bit integer).

Am I stuck doing an `#ifdef` for the compiler to make the correct format string, or is there a smarter/easier way to do this?

**Note**: this is not a duplicate of how to print a `int64_t`, because GLuint64 is defined as different concrete types at the top of the standard glext.h header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a int64\_t type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c)

Comment: @BDL - see clarification at the bottom, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: It can actually be one of four types: `unsigned long int`, `unsigned long long int`, `unsigned __int64`, `uint64_t`. The duplicate works for all of them on their respective systems. (tested with gcc, clang and vc++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is simple: *don't*.

If you want to printf a `GLuint64`, then first cast it to a well-defined C++ type, such as `unsigned long long`. Since the input type is required by the OpenGL specification to be exactly 64-bits in size, and `unsigned long long` is *required* by the C specification (and thus by inclusion C++) to be at least 64-bits in size, the conversion should be lossless.