# Lua C API doesn't work with pointer

Tags: c++, c, lua

This is what I did.
I created a struct and a static function in my C++ code

```
struct ItemDefinition {
  int64_t price;
};
int static getPrice(lua_State* L) {

  ItemDefinition* def = (ItemDefinition*)lua_touserdata(L, 1);
  printf("%p\n", def);
  printf("%d\n", def->price);
  return 0;
}
```

I also registered the function in lua and initialized an ItemDefination object.

```
ItemDefinition def;
def.price = 120;
lua_pushlightuserdata(lua_state_, (ItemDefinition*)&def);
lua_setglobal(lua_state_, "def");
luaL_Reg module[] = {{"getPrice", &getPrice}, {NULL, NULL}};
```

from my Lua script, I just simply call the function

```
getPrice(def)
```

if works fine if I just print out the def's address. So I'm sure the function get called successfully. However, if I'm trying to get `def->price`, I will get an error from address sanitizer `"==283789==ERROR  stack use after return"` 
I'm not familiar with both [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [lua](/questions/tagged/lua). Could you please help where the problem could be?

Comment: The format specifier `%d` is incorrect for the type `int64_t`.

Comment: BTW, I'm trying to create a global object, the "def" in my example and it will be called for many times.. So the test actually call the getPrice method many times. I'm not sure if this behavior causes the problem?

Comment: Please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c/9225648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve the issue, NVM. It's actually because the pointer issue.