# Multiplication of positive integers results in 0 (__int64)

Tags: c

I am trying to multiply four integers into a `__int64`. The value it should have is `4096 * 1024 * 64 * 64 = 17,179,869,184`. This is too large of a number to store in an `int`, thats why I'm using `__int64`.
The output I get however is `0`.

I've tried casting every single one of the integers to a `__int64`, which doesnt change the output from being `0`.
Also, if I check with a debugger, the value of `test` is in fact `0`, so it is not a problem with outputting it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    __int64 test = (__int64)4096 * (__int64)1024 * (__int64)64 * (__int64)64;
    printf("%d", test);
    getchar();
}
```

The output:

```
0
```

The expected output:

```
17179869184
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation is probably OK, try changing your output format to long form, so :

```
printf("%lld", test);
```

EDIT: should cast type as well, so :

```
printf("%lld", (long long)test);
```

Comment: It should be `long long` then, `%lld`, and `test` should be cast to `long long`.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I have checked with the VS2015 debugger that the value of test is in fact 0. Printing with ```%ld``` does not change the output. Also, calculations performed with ```test``` result in wrong results, so it does have a wrong value.

Comment: @NielsSlotboom no, it's not zero, it's 0x400000000. See [the assembly output from MSVC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G0ayW6). You just have to use the correct type specifier and make sure that the type passed is correct.

Comment: I have realized a mistake. In my project I'm working on (so not the sample code above) I'm not casting the values to ```__int64```.  Thats why checking with the VS2015 debugger does show the value to be ```0```, because it actually gets computed wrong. In the sample code I do cast the values, so it computes correctly. If you could edit your answer to say ```%lld``` insted of ```%ld``` then I will accept it.

Comment: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat=]`, `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` suggest `%I64d`

Comment: Better one there: [How to print a int64_t type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225648/2498790)

Answer (score 0):

Your `printf` format specifier is wrong: `%d` is for `int`, whereas the argument is `__int64`.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I have checked with the VS2015 debugger that the value of ```test``` is in fact 0. Printing with ```%ld``` does not change the output.