# int64_t changes value when passed to a function

Tags: c++, command-line

I read a large value(300000000000) from command line and pass it to the function RR. The correct value is printed in main but incorrect value is printed in RR. From what I understand, the value printed in main is the 64 bit value but the value printed in RR is a 32bit int version. However that does not really make sense since I pass a int64_t as an argument and RR receives int64_t as an argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
struct Process
{
   int64_t id, arrivalTime, burstTime;
};
void RR(vector<Process> &vec, int64_t timeSlice, int64_t optimal_step){
  printf("timeslice: %d\n", timeSlice);
  exit(0);
}


vector<Process> parseInputFile(string filename, vector<Process> &vec){
  ifstream inFile;
  int64_t arrival;
  int64_t burst;
  inFile.open(filename);

    if (!inFile) {
      cerr << "Unable to open file ";
      cout<<filename<<endl;
      exit(1);   // call system to stop
    }
    for ( int64_t i = 0; i>=0; i++) {
      inFile >> arrival;
      inFile >> burst;
      if(!inFile){
        inFile.close();
        return vec;
      }
      vec.push_back({i, arrival, burst});
    }
    return vec;

}


int main(int argc, char * const argv[]){
  string filename = argv[1];
  int64_t timeSlice = -1;
  vector<Process> vec;
  int64_t optimal_step = 1;
  vec = parseInputFile(filename, vec);


  if(argc == 3){
      timeSlice = strtoll(argv[2], nullptr, 10);

      cout<<"timeslice: "<<timeSlice<<endl;
      RR(vec, timeSlice, optimal_step);
  }


}
```

Expected output

```
timeslice: 300000000000
timeslice: 300000000000
```

Actual output:

```
timeslice: 300000000000
timeslice: -647710720
```

How to run:

```
./a.out [.txt file] 300000000000
```

Comment: [Turn on compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aezPgA) (not that its suggestion is perfect, but you should take all compiler suggestions with a grain of salt).

Comment: Yep, cout prints it out correctly. Thank you

Comment: To fix the `printf()`, see [How to print a int64_t type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/)