# Machine-independent printf() of int64_t?

Tags: c, gcc, printf

Consider the following snippet, compiled with `gcc -Wall` for two different architectures:

```
int64_t x;
printf("A: %ld\n", x);
printf("B: %lld\n", x);
```

When compiling for a 32 bit machine, the compiler complains about "A":

> format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'int64_t' {aka 'long long int'}

When compiling for a 64 bit machine, the compiler complains about "B":

> format '%lld' expects argument of type 'long long int', but argument 2 has type 'int64_t' {aka 'long int'}

**The question:** What is a sensible machine-independent way to `printf()` `int64_t`?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to print a int64_t type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9225567/45249).

Comment: Agreed.  Though answer gets right to the point!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header `inttypes.h` contains portable conversion specifiers for `printf` and `scanf` family of functions. (It also internally includes `stdint.h`.)

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t x = ...;
printf("%"PRIi64, x);
```

See the C standard C17 7.8.1 for details.