# Why the multiplication result is wrong on this code?

Tags: c, math, multiplication

I using `this code` (is working in progress)

the part

```
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int b = 512;
    i = atoi(line);
    unsigned int linekb = (i * b);
```

return..

```
The size in 512b blocks of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 is 41929587 
The size in Bytes of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 is 4288079360
```

which is wrong because

```
41929587 * 512 = 21467948544
```

I have tried using `int` and `%d` instead of `unsigned int` but give also bad result

```
The size in 512b blocks of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0del is 41929587 
The size in Bytes of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 is -6887936
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: 21,467,948,544 cannot be represented in a 32-bit integer.

Comment: long long int can be the right choice?

Comment: I'm trying now with int64_t

Answer (score 1):

Solution found, using the `int64_t` type.

I have to add these new lines:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
int64_t t;
printf("%" PRId64 "\n", t);
```

for correctness I report that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225567/how-to-portably-print-a-int64-t-type-in-c) the solution.

This is [my working code](https://pastebin.com/raw/vgVsCpGt) now:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file = popen("/usr/sbin/prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 | /usr/local/bin/grep 'slice 0' -A 2 | grep length | cut -d : -f 3 | cut -d '(' -f 1 | cut -c 2-1000", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[128];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) == NULL) {
        perror("fgets");
        return 1;
    }

    pclose(file);

    size_t len = strlen(line);
    if (len > 0 && line[len - 1] == '\n') {
        line[len - 1] = '\0';
    }

    int64_t i;
    int64_t b=512;
    i = atoi(line);
    int64_t lineb = (i*b);
    int64_t linekb = (i*b/1024);
    int64_t linemb = (i*b/1024/1024);

    printf("The size in 512b blocks of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0del is %s\n", line);
    printf("The size in Bytes of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 is " "%" PRId64 " bytes" "\n", lineb);
    printf("The size in Bytes of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 is " "%" PRId64 " kb" "\n", linekb);
    printf("The size in Bytes of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 is " "%" PRId64 " mb" "\n", linemb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `unsigned long long` is a simpler solution.

Comment: In your code, you should replace `i = atoi(line);` with `i = strtoull(line, NULL, 0);`