# Want a solution for printf

Tags: c, compiler-construction, printf, format-specifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to printf uint64_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132399/how-to-printf-uint64-t)

I want to print `u_int64_t` in C.
I want to know the format specifier for this?
I am a C user, I want to do a `printf()`.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how to printf uint64_t](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8132399/62576).

Comment: I want it for u_int64_t. Are both the same? I mean uint64_t and u_int64_t..?

Comment: This question isn't an exact duplicate of the uint64_t question.  The `u_int8_t`, `u_int16_t`, `u_int32_t`, and `u_int64_t` types show up in the Linux header: `/usr/include/sys/types.h`, with the comment `But these were defined by ISO C without the first '_'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t t = 42;
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", t);
```

Comment: it is u_int64_t. So, I got confused.? Do they mean the same.?

Comment: C has not standard C type named  `u_int64_t` but has an optional type named `uint64_t`.

Comment: I am working on linux, and I came across this u_int64_t and I got confused, So, if I print the way you say, would it be fine..?

Comment: You have to check what type `u_int64_t` is an alias for but assuming the type is a 64-bit width type,  the `PRIu64` macro is the way to go.

Comment: It works, wooo. What is the 'PRIu64' meaning which is in the 'printf'?

Comment: @aasa it's a macro that expands to a string literal with the desired conversion specifier, for example `"lu"` or `"llu"` depending on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `L` modifier for 64-bit integers, eg:

```
u_in64_t number;
printf("%Lu", number);
```

Comment: `L` is not a C standard conversion specifier

Comment: So, what is the final printf format?

Comment: Standard C does not have its own 64-bit integer data type, but the compiler may support `long long ...`, which could be typedefed.  `long long ...` uses the `ll` modifier instead.  But some compilers also support the `L` modifier.

Comment: Standard C does not guarantee a 64-bit integer data type, but if the platform has a 64-bit integer data type, then a C99 implementation is required to provide `uint64_t` (section 7.18.1.1). `uint_least64_t` and `uint_fast64_t` are required (sections 7.18.1.2 and 7.18.1.3), and there are corresponding `PRIu64`/`PRIuLEAST64`/`PRIuFAST64` macros.