# "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS" gnu compiler option

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I am cleaning up my Makefile and try to understand what is actually happening there. I came across said option. It must enable some macros to guarantee compatibility with older C libraries, but i could not find its purpose. What does the gnu compiler (g++) option

```
g++ -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
```

mean or do? Is it even necessary for g++?

PS: Im working under Linux

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8132440/516138 You've probably already found this!

Comment: No i havent. Thanks Nick. I add some of its content in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link of Nick, I conclude that it is not required for g++. It has to do with C's inttype.h and printf. From the link

> In particular, the symbol __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS, mentioned in footnote
>   182 of the C standard, plays no role in C++.