# printf and %llu vs %lu on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, types, integer, long-integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to printf uint64_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132399/how-to-printf-uint64-t)

Why is it that on my 64-bit Mac (I am using Clang) the `uint64_t` type is `unsigned long long` while on 64-bit Ubuntu the `uint64_t` type is `unsigned long`?

This makes it very difficult for me to get my `printf` calls to not give compiler warnings (or indeed even to work) under both environments.

I can try to use macros to try to choose the correct string (`#define LU` either `%llu` or `%lu`, and in the process uglifying the `printf` strings a bit) but on the Mac I've got a 64-bit word size (so `_LP64` would be defined and `UINTPTR_MAX != 0xffffffff`) and yet it still uses `long long` for the 64 bit int types.

```
// printf macro switch (for the uint64_t's)
#if UINTPTR_MAX == 0xffffffff 
   // 32-bit
#  define LU "%llu"
#else 
   // assume 64-bit
   // special case for OS X because it is strange
   // should actually check also for __MACH__ 
#  ifdef __APPLE__
#    define LU "%llu"
#  else
#    define LU "%lu"
#  endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macros are already defined for you in `<cinttypes>`. Try

```
printf("%"PRIu64, x);
```

Or, even better, use C++ features like

```
std::cout << x;
```

which will select the proper << operator for your variable type.

Comment: `fatal error: 'cinttypes' file not found`

Comment: This is a C++11 header, so it depends on how compatible your compiler is. If supporting C99, there will be an `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. I did actually find that file in the C++11 `libc++`. Well, hopefully this `inttypes.h` header is available on my other platforms as well, here's the replacement for my code snippet in the question: `#define LU "%"PRIu64`

Comment: The `std::cout << x;` statement is not equivalent to the printf(). If you write the equivalent statement you will see why people still use printf() to format numbers. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to promote via static cast:

```
some_type i = 5;
printf("our value is: %llu", (unsigned long long)i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying type of `uint64_t` can be whatever the implementation like as long as it is in fact 64 bits.

Obviously in C++ the preferred solution is to use iostreams instead of `printf` as then the problem disappears. But you can always just cast the value passed to `printf` to make the type always correct:

`printf("%llu", static_cast<unsigned long long>(value));`

Comment: Hmm... Lengthens the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the standard's not very specific on the sizes of these types... The only guarantee is that `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`.

You can use macros like you said, or you could try using `%zu` or `%ju` which are used to print out `size_t` and `uintmax_t` types (both 64-bit on OS X, haven't tested on Ubuntu). I don't think there are any other options.

Comment: I have never seen `%zu` or `%ju` before. How standard is this?

Comment: It's standard and should be perfectly portable. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Oh wow. Must have missed it.

Comment: %zu is for size_t data types, that differ in different platforms so you can make sure the correct interpretation is made. Is basically the formatting of a size_t as unsinged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure other people will tell you to use BOOST.  So in the interest of providing a solution that is not dependent on BOOST:

I have run into the same problem so often that I gave up and wrote my own helper macros that feed into %s instead of any brand of `%llu` or `%lu` or whatever.  I also found it helpful for helping maintain a sane format string design, and for providing better (and more consistent) hex and pointer printouts.  There are two caveats:

1. You can't easily combine extra formatting parameters (left/right justification, padding, etc) -- but then you can't really do that with the `LU` macro either.
2. this approach does add additional overhead to the task for formatting and printing strings.  However, I write performance-critical apps and I haven't noticed it being an issue except in Microsoft's Visual C++ debug builds (which take about 200x longer to allocate and free heap memory than normal because of all the internal validation and corruption checks).

Here's a comparison:

```
printf( "Value1: " LU ", Value2: " LU, somevar1, somevar2 );
```

vs.

```
printf( "Value1: %s, Value2: %s", cStrDec(somevar1), cStrDec(somevar2) );
```

To make it work, I used a set of macros and templates like this:

```
#define cStrHex( value )        StrHex    ( value ).c_str()
#define cStrDec( value )        StrDecimal( value ).c_str()

std::string StrDecimal( const uint64_t& src )
{
    return StrFormat( "%u%u", uint32_t(src>>32), uint32_t(src) );
}

std::string StrDecimal( const int64_t& src )
{
    return StrFormat( "%d%u", uint32_t(src>>32), uint32_t(src) );
}

std::string StrDecimal( const uint32_t& src )
{
    return StrFormat( "%u", src );
}

std::string StrDecimal( const int32_t& src )
{
    return StrFormat( "%d", src );
}

std::string StrHex( const uint64_t& src, const char* sep="_" )
{
    return StrFormat( "0x%08x%s%08x", uint32_t(src>>32), sep, uint32_t(src) );
}

std::string StrHex( const int64_t& src, const char* sep="_" )
{
    return StrFormat( "0x%08x%s%08x", uint32_t(src>>32), sep, uint32_t(src) );
}

// Repeat implementations for int32_t, int16_t, int8_t, etc.
// I also did versions for 128-bit and 256-bit SIMD types, since I use those.
// [...]
```

My string formatting functions are based on the now-preferred method of formatting directly into a std::string, which looks something like this:

```
std::string StrFormatV( const char* fmt, va_list list )
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    int destSize = _vscprintf( fmt, list );
#else
    va_list l2;
    va_copy(l2, list);
    int destSize = vsnprintf( nullptr, 0, fmt, l2 );
    va_end(l2);
#endif
    std::string result;
    result.resize( destSize );
    if (destSize!=0)
            vsnprintf( &result[0], destSize+1, fmt, list );
    return result;
}

std::string StrFormat( const char* fmt, ... )
{
    va_list list;
    va_start( list, fmt );
    std::string result = StrFormatV( fmt, list );
    va_end( list );

    return *this;
}
```