# A funny thing with sprintf

Tags: c, linux, windows, printf

I'm so confused with sprintf that a funny problem with different platfrom.
Code :

```
int main () 
{
    char sql[1024];
    uint32_t app_id = 32;
    uint64_t task_id = 64;
    sprintf(sql, "%u, %u", task_id, app_id);
    printf ("%s\n", sql);
    return 0;
}
```

The result in console (MSVC2010 debug/release): **64, 0**

But the same code in console(CentOS64 gcc4.4.6): **64, 32**

Any guy will help me, tks!

-------------updated--------------------------

Thanks guys. I have read this article: [sprintf for unsigned _int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140871/sprintf-for-unsigned-int64)

Actually, `PRIu64` in `"inttypes.h"` defined: `I64u`which is not supported on windows. So I can write like this:

```
sprintf(sql, "%I64u, %I32u", task_id, app_id);
```

Comment: `%u` isn't the correct format specifier for `uint64_t`.  Try `PRIu64` instead.

Comment: On windows, a uint64_t is an unsigned long long; you need to stick with the suggestion from @simonc if you want it to work properly across the board

Comment: `#include <inttypes.h>` and `sprintf(sql, "%"PRIu64",%"PRIu32, task_id, app_id);` will do the trick

Comment: really a nice link you added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `%llu` format string for `task_id` in `sprintf()`as follows:

```
sprintf(sql, "%llu, %u", task_id, app_id);
//             ^
//            for: long long unsigned int
```

Edit: As @[Simonc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311966/simonc) suggested its better to use: `PRIu32` and `PRIu64` macros  defined in `<inttypes.h>` (as you have Linux tag) do like:

```
sprintf(sql, "%"PRIu64", %"PRIu32"", task_id, app_id);
//               ^           ^
//       for:   uint64_t    uint32_t
```

Comment: What has this to do with the actual print out: `64, 0`?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't think the `PRId32` is required.  I think a format string of `"%"PRIu64", %u"` should be fine.  Also, note that you'd want the macros for unsigned ints, so `PRIu64` (and likewise if you want to use the equivalent macro for the `uint32_t`).

Comment: @simonc yes it doesn't need its macro in `inttypes.h`. defined like `#define PRId32      "ld"` Thanks for the edit :) .

Comment: On 32-bit machines task_id is long long unsigned int. Try to compile it with -Wextra option of gcc!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, no, you don't need extra "" after PRId32, check-it with `cpp` or `gcc -E`

Comment: @DavidRF Yes I have no extra `"`,  that is what I have conversation in  with simonc

Comment: @Claudio you are possible correct but ` PRId64` will take care for this :)

Comment: @DavidRF No problem David :), normally I do same mistakes.

Comment: Down-vote are **wrong** because if `%u` correct for `uint32_t` (as OP says) then `%lu` is correct for  `uint64_t`. Additionally I have given better technique.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Why would %lu be correct ? On 32 bit linux, long is 32 bit. On 64 bit windows, long is 32 bit. On 64 bit linux, long is 64 bit, so it may work in that case, but that'd still be correct for only 1 of 3 platforms.

Comment: Got it Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073877/printf-and-llu-vs-lu-on-os-x) .. actually it is really hard to understand --Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks very much to improve my answers, specially when I make English mistakes. I always notice edits in [revisions-history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17065245/revisions) made by you that help me to improve/learn tips.

Comment: @Claudio I realized after reading few more posts and @ nos's commnet that `%lu` was wrong. I should have considered your suggestion carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Format string `%lu` won't work on 32-bit machines, where a 64-bit variable is `long long`.

Use `%llu` for 64-bit instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main () 
{
    char sql[1024];
    uint32_t app_id = 32;
    uint64_t task_id = 64;
    sprintf(sql, "%llu, %u", task_id, app_id);
    printf ("%s\n", sql);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong. First of all, `ll` stands for `long long`, while you may want to use just `long`. Also, this has nothing to do with the actual print out: `64, 0`.

Comment: uint64 on linux does work as a long long. However, this won't address it on windows. a normal unsigned int is u, long is lu and long long is llu

Comment: On my 32-bit Linux machine gcc 4.7 complains if I use just %lu. The reason is that 64-bit unsigned int are long long.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs If you use long, there are many real world platform it will not work on. long is not 64 bit on all platforms. long long is 64 bits on all current platforms that supports long long (though there's nothing wong with a platform implementing long long with > 64 bits, none do at the moment though)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to what others have said:

Giving

```
sprintf(sql, "%u, %u", app_id, task_id);
```

instead of

```
sprintf(sql, "%u, %u", task_id, app_id);
```

gives an output `32, 64`!!

No need to worry! Here is why:
`task_id` is pushed to stack (higher 4 bytes first and lower 4 bytes second) before pushing `app_id` (as arguments to `sprintf`). But when `sprintf` goes to take arguments, it pops 4 bytes + 4 bytes from stack, as two %u are specified in the format. So it takes the lower 4 bytes of `task_id` and prints it as `unsigned int`.

The same happens when `sprintf(sql, "%u, %u", task_id, app_id);` is given.

`app_id` is pushed first and `task_id` next. But when sprintf reads, it pops two 4 bytes, `64` (the lower 4 bytes of task_id) and `00` (higher 4 byte of `task_id` and prints `64, 00`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sprintf(sql, "%lu, %u", task_id, app_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the proper formatting specifier for `uint64_t` is `PRIu64` (*not* `lu`, since there's no guarantee that `uint64_t` is `long`).

So, you need to use that:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

char sql[1024];
uint32_t app_id = 32;
uint64_t task_id = 64;
sprintf(sql, "%u, %" PRIu64, app_id, task_id);
printf ("%s\n", sql);
```

Comment: No, app_id (last param) is uint_32

Comment: I think your format specifiers are the wrong way round.  `task_id` is the `uint64_t`

Comment: Is `#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` neccesary? it compiles fine without it on gcc 4.7.2

Comment: @AlterMann I think it's for support when compiling with g++

Answer (score -1):

The format specifier is wrong. The `printf` function doesn't know what kind of parameters are passed to it, it can only deduce this from the format specifiers. So when you pass a 64bit integer to it, and tell the function that you passed only a long (32bit) then it takes only half of the 64 bit value passed in. Depending on the architecture, the correct result might be printed or not. The reason is how the number is stored in memory and what the printf function sees when it reads the `long` value.

If the long value happens to have the same number of bits or the value is stored in memory in such a way that the expected result happens to be in the right place, the correct value could be printed, but of course, the code would still be wrong, though it appears to work.