# How can be size of variable guaranteed

Tags: c, typedef

I have variable that must be 16 bit long. How should I define it to be exactly 16 bit independently on the platform?

I can define it as `short`, but depending on the platform it can be 16 bits or more.

Comment: You can use `int16_t` (see [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)), but that might not be defined in all compilers. Which one are you using?

Comment: accordingly you may use format string macros `PRIu64`, `PRIu32`, `PRIu16` defined in `<inttypes.h>` : check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065203/a-funny-thing-with-sprintf/17065245#17065245)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using C99, then use `uint16_t` (or `int16_t`) from [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).  These are guaranteed to exist so long as the compiler has an underlying 16-bit type available.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int16_t` for signed integer or `uint16_t` for unsigned, The header `inttypes.h` and `stdint.h` are introduced in C99. If you are using C89, define your own type.

Note that they may not be provided in certain implementation, according to C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §7.20 *Integer types*

> For each type described herein that the implementation provides) shall declare that typedef name and define the associated macros. Conversely, for each type described herein that the implementation does not provide, shall not declare that typedef name nor shall it define the associated macros. An implementation shall provide those types described as ‘‘required’’, but need not provide any of the others (described as ‘optional’’).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a portable unsigned 16-bit integer, use `uint16_t` and for signed 16-bit integer, use `int16_t`.

`inttypes.h` and `stdint.h` are both introduced in `C99`. If you are using `C89`, you have to define your own type.

Comment: How should it define my own type?

Comment: @Alex one suitable option would be to use bitfields to simulate a 16 bit long variable.

Answer (score 0):

if `<stdint.h>` and `int16_t` are not available, a workaround could be a bitfield. Since a bitfield is only valid inside a struct or union, it has to be wrapped into one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct auw {
    int sixteen :16;
        };

int main(void)
{

struct auw one = {16*1024 }, two, result;

two = one; /* assigmment is easy*/

        /* but addition is a bit more painful */
result.sixteen = one.sixteen + two.sixteen -1;

printf("Result=%d\n", (int) result.sixteen );

return 0;
}
```