# printf format for unsigned __int64 on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, printf, unsigned

I need to print a `ULONGLONG` value (`unsigned __int64`). What format should i use in `printf` ?
I found `%llu` in another question but they say it is for linux only.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use std::cout? It should just work.

Comment: I can't. The function i use is a wrapper with variable argument list that uses printf and which i can't modify.

Comment: Read this also: [A funny thing with sprintf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065203/a-funny-thing-with-sprintf/17065245#17065245)

Comment: `%llu` is not for Linux only; it's the format defined by the ISO C standard, starting with the 1999 edition. Unfortunately, Microsoft's C implementation doesn't support C99 or later. In other words, it's Windows, not Linux, that's the special case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using Google to search for “Visual Studio printf unsigned __int64” produces [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215(v=vs.60).aspx) as the first result, which says you can use the prefix `I64`, so the format specifier would be `%I64u`.

Comment: Other choice is macro `PRIu64` defined in  `inttypes.h`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `PRIu64` and `inttypes.h` are not supported in Visual Studio (at least, not by Microsoft).

Comment: Be aware that both `__int64` and `%I64u` are specific to Visual Studio, so your code will not be portable to any other implementation.

Comment: It's not in the plans :P

Comment: Actually... using Google to search for "Visual Studio printf unsigned __int64" produces *THIS* page as the first result. Maybe remove the Google-shaming to future-proof your answer?

Answer (score 16):

`%llu` is the standard way to  print `unsigned long long`, it's not just for Linux, it's actually in C99. So the problem is actually to use a C99-compatible compiler, i.e, not Visual Studio.

C99 7.19.6 *Formatted input/output functions*

> ll(ell-ell) Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a
>   long long int or unsigned long long int argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to along long int argument.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with this if i could choose what software i'm working with.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft does not define a `ULONGLONG` to be an `unsigned long long`. Per [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230393.aspx), it is an `unsigned __int64`. Using a format for `unsigned long long` might or might not work, but, if you want your code to survive compiler updates and future migrations, you should stick to the specification of the type.

Comment: @Virus721 Your question says you need to use it in Windows, not saying Visual Studio.

Comment: @YuHao: `ULONGLONG` and `__int64` are types in Visual Studio.

Comment: @EricPostpischil didn't know that, sorry about that. But I think it's still worth pointing out `%llu` is not Linux only. It is Microsoft's fault not to follow C99.

Comment: @YuHao It is not a fault. It is by design decision. Microsoft Visual C++ is not a C but C++ compiler which supports as much C standard(s) as C++98|03|11|14|17|... require

Comment: @mloskot that is absolutely incorrect. Msvc supports e.g. naming variables `new` and `private` which goes far beyond what C++ requires

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "we don't say much about later C standards conformance, and this is intentional. MSVC includes a C89/C90 compliant compile (...) Support for later C standards is limited to the subset required by the C++ standard."  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/407#issuecomment-417922008

Comment: %lld also worked for me although I think %llu is better

Comment: @mloskot [C++11 **1.1 Scope**, paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c%2B%2B/c%2B%2B11_n3337.txt) (bolding mine): "C++ is a general purpose programming language based on the **C programming language as described in ISO/IEC 9899:1999** Programming languages"  A **standard-conforming** C++11 implementation must therefore provide C99's `%ll` format modifier via `cstdio` and therefore the `[unsigned] long long` types.  Any Microsoft implementation of C++11 that does not provide `[unsigned] long long` does not comply with the C++ standard.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend you use [`PRIu64`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) format specified from a standard C library. It was designed to provide users with a format specifier for unsigned 64-bit integer across different architectures.

Here is an example (in C, not C++):

```
#include <stdint.h>   /* For uint64_t */
#include <inttypes.h> /* For PRIu64 */
#include <stdio.h>    /* For printf */
#include <stdlib.h>   /* For exit status */

int main()
{
    uint64_t n = 1986;
    printf("And the winning number is.... %" PRIu64 "!\n", n);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio does not support `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h`. It does not support C 1999. There are [third-party implementations of them](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Have guys at Microsoft completely lost their minds? :(

Comment: Thanks for your help, but %I64d does the job.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fwiw, Visual Studio began `stdint.h` support with VS2010 (is use it regularly).But they still missed the bus on C99 (and from what I read, they not even bothering with it). Ugh.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Does it support `inttypes.h` too?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not that i've seen, as evidenced by numerous wailings a gnashing of teeth from VS2010 articles across this great web of ours.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Microsoft is more interested in making money than in conforming to ISO standards. Apparently they've decided, so far, that C99 support is not worth the investment that would be required. I don't like it either (it slows general adoption of C99, to say nothing of C11), but I'm not in a position to judge whether their decision is correct in the context in which they've made it. They're under no obligation to support C99 -- or to support C at all, for that matter. (How many C compilers have *you* written?)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Totally agree with you on this one. Microsoft does not own us anything. I just wish that a company with such a resource and influence would do more good for the society and programmers in general. So far they just create inconsistencies :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: They have said that they'll add at least some C99 support in the next release of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Printf has different format specifiers for `unsigned long long` depending on the compiler, I have seen `%llu` and `%Lu`. In general I would advice you to use `std::cout` and similar instead.

Comment: The question is tagged both "c" and "c++". In C, `std::cout` is nothing more than a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around for HEX output

```
printf("%08X%08X", static_cast<UINT32>((u64>>32)&0xFFFFFFFF), static_cast<UINT32>(u64)&0xFFFFFFFF));
```

Answer (score 0):

For guys who forget all the time like me,
If you use Visual Studio (choosing MSVC compiler, to be specific),

`%I64u` for `uint64_t` == `unsigned __int64` == `unsigned long long`

`%I64d` for `int64_t` == `__int64` == `long long`

`%Iu` for `size_t` (==`unsigned __int64` in win64, else `unsigned int`)

You should check this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170) for the details, or just [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170#size) :)
also, if interested, other MSDNs like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-170) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=msvc-170).

<sub><sub><sub># C++ Windows format string MSVC Visual Studio size_t int64_t uint64_t</sub></sub></sub>