# warning: format ‘%llx’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘off64_t *’ [-Wformat]

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit

When I compile my code under Linux x64 (under x86 no warning) I get the following warning `warning: format ‘%llx’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘off64_t *’ [-Wformat]`

my code snippet:

```
if(maps && mem != -1) {
        char buf[BUFSIZ + 1];

        while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, maps)) {
                off64_t start, end;

                sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", &start, &end);
                dump_region(mem, start, end);
        }
}
```

How should I cast it to get no warning?

EDIT:

Should I cast like this?:

```
sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", (long long unsigned int *)&start, (long long unsigned int *)&end);
```

Comment: use `PRIu64`  instead of %llx

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065203/a-funny-thing-with-sprintf/17065245#17065245) how to use it is a macro.

Comment: something like `sscanf(buf, "%"PRIu64"-%"PRIu64, &start, &end);` ? compiles with no warning but the code doesn't work now.

Comment: yes but what is in buffer, notice you are using `-` in scanf that is the reason I didn't post an answer. `buff` should be as `"3223-2254"`

Comment: Here the full code: http://pastebin.com/E1zLJRjx maybe you can give an example and post as answer. By the way, the code must compile under x64 and x86 also. Thanks!

Comment: give it a try it should work... else remove - in format string

Comment: What about `sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", (long long unsigned int *)&start, (long long unsigned int *)&end);` ? Compiles without warning and code works.

Comment: why do you bother to cast `llx` may not be 64 bit on some system.

Comment: btw dons't PRIu64 worked without warning ?

Comment: Is 64bit on 64bit systems and 32bit on x86 systems. This way it works on both. That's why I need to use `off64_t` for big files.

Comment: With `PRIu64` compiled without warning but the compiled code didn't work at all.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan Suggestions to use PRI... should be SCN... for scanf(). PRI... is for the printf() family.

Comment: @chux Thanks I didn't know this :) do you know any reason or give some link that why to different format string because generally we uses e.g. `%d` for both scan as well as print.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I was schooled on this via SO too.

Comment: @chux ok if you gets some link please share with me.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan For types >= sizeof(int), I would expect the formats to be the same.  Maybe not for smaller types?  Do not have a handy link.

Comment: @chux I will read about this and will share if I find something exact info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 approaches come to mind using `sscanf()` to read a non-standard integer types like `off64_t`.

1) Try to divine the correct format specifier through various conditions (`#if ...`) and use `sscanf()`.  Assuming it is `SCNx64` below

```
 #include <inttypes.h>
 off64_t start, end;
 if (2 == sscanf(buf, "%" SCNx64 "-%" SCNx64, &start, &end)) Success();
```

2) Use `sscanf()` with the largest int and convert afterwards.

```
 #include <inttypes.h>
 off64_t start, end;
 uintmax_t startmax, endmax;
 if (2 == sscanf(buf, "%" SCNxMAX "-%" SCNxMAX, &startmax, &endmax)) Success();

 start = (off64_t) startmax;
 end   = (off64_t) endmax;

 // Perform range test as needed
 if start != startmax) ...
```

BTW: Suggestions to use `PRI...` should be `SCN...` for `scanf()`. `PRI...` is for the `printf()` family.

Always good to check `sscanf()` results.

Comment: Good idea. Casting to `long long unsigned int` is wrong here, because it works?

Comment: Not sure what cast you refer, here or in question.  I'll assume the cast from your post.  You certainly do not want to use `(long long unsigned int *)&start`.  `start` is type `off64_t` which _may_ differ from `long long unsigned int`.  If `off64_t` was _always_ the same as `long long unsigned int`, it would not exist.  So if `(long long unsigned int *)&start` "works" for you today, it may not work on another platform or with a later compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the best way I could find so far is casting:

```
#if __GNUC__
  #if __x86_64__ || __ppc64__
    #define ENV64BIT
    #define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
    #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
  #else
    #define ENV32BIT
  #endif
#endif
```

then

```
#if defined(ENV64BIT)
    sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", (long long unsigned int *)&start, (long long unsigned int *)&end);
#else
    sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", &start, &end);
#endif
```