# "%llu" against "u64" causes warnings

Tags: gcc, printf, warnings

I got following warning while compiling on x86_64 gcc:

```
warning: format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but     
argument 2 has type ‘u64’
```

Both unsigned long long and u64 are 64-bit unsigned integer, aren't they?
So what is exactly the difference that gcc considers about them?

Comment: could you post the code that causes this warning?

Answer (score 0):

In short llu can be **64 bit** but this is not a must. It all depends on the machine, compiler etc. You should consider using `PRIu64` in your case.

Your question has already been answered in detail here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073877/printf-and-llu-vs-lu-on-os-x)