# Strange compiler behavior with PRIu64 in C++

Tags: c++, g++

I have some code in my c++ file that looks like this:

```
#include <cinttypes>
....
LOG_INFO("%s duration: %" PRId64 "\n", tag.c_str(), timestamp);
```

And it can be compiled successfully with flag `-std=c++11`.

But it is failed been compiling on another machine with following error:

```
base/utils.h:68:31: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRId64’
```

unless I add flag `-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS`.

The first machine has

```
gcc "4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)",
```

the other machine has

```
gcc "4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)"
```

and using

```
touch foo.h ; gcc -E -dM foo.h
```

got same result expect the version macro.

I'm confused why the second machine needs `-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` to compile PRId64?

Comment: [The notes section in this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer#Notes) should be helpful.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535556/why-doesnt-priu64-work-in-this-code

Comment: Are you sure the GCC version difference is causing this? It looks like more a difference in *other* header files.

Comment: @Martin, I'm using `-std=c++11` so I expected no `-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` needed.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, I don't think the GCC version causing this. I have no idea why this happened.