# storing pointers to line numbers of a file stored on disk in C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to store pointers to file's line numbers in an array and later I want to retrieve the specified line from disk. I can not store pointer to line number directly as when I read the file back the memory locations would have changed. So, I am storing the offset from the beginning of the file instead. For storing the offset I am using "uint_64t". However since my file size is 200GB therefore "uint_64t" is not able to represent all the offsets.

I have the following questions:

1. Other than storing offsets, is there some other way by which I may store pointers to file stored on disk.
2. Is there some other data structure which I may use (other than uint64_t).

Comment: uint64_t can take 64bit numbers: that is 1.7180e+10 GB, what exactly is not working?

Comment: You'd need 38 bits to represent 200Gb worth of offsets so a `uint64_t` should be fine

Comment: @PatrickB.: Not %llu?

Comment: @thejh you're right, it should `%llu`, however on the 64bit-platform  `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` have are both 64bit.

Comment: @PatrickB.: Still `%lu`, not `%ul`, right?

Comment: The proper format flag for `uint64_t` is [`PRIu64`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132399/how-to-printf-uint64-t).

Comment: @PatrickB. Not if the platform is 64-bit Windows; there `unsigned long` is a 32-bit quantity and `unsigned long long`, if it is supported at all, will be 64-bit.  The format specifier on Windows 64-bit would be `%I64u`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On POSIX systems, `off_t` is the standard type for file offsets. It's probably a 64-bit type, though, just like `uint64_t`, as those can hold values on the order of 2e11 without trouble.

Answer (score 7):

You're wrong. A `uint64_t` is 64 bits, so you can express offsets in files up to `2^64 bytes = 18.45 exabytes` with it. According to Wolfram Alpha, you can compare that to:

- estimated information content of all human knowledge (as of mid-1999) (~ 12 EB )
- 180 × purported storage capacity of the character Data in Star Trek: The Next Generation ( 8×10^17 b )

No way your files are that big. :)

Comment: +1 for Star Trek reference AND Wolfram Alpha (but I can only vote up once)

Answer (score 5):

A 64-bit unsigned integer should be plenty large enough to store the byte offset into a 200 GB file.

```
200 GB = 200 GB * 1024 MB/GB * 1024 KB/MB * 1024 Bytes/KB = 214,748,364,800 Bytes
```

However, a 64-bit integer has a range:

```
Low: 0, High: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

I don't see the issue.  You can easily index into every byte of that file.  As a matter of fact, you could index into every bit of the file and still have lot's of room for growth!

Comment: Actually, to exceed the 64-bits range, the file would have to be bigger than the storage capacity of any data-center I have ever heard of :)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow some encoding schemes to store an offset value.

Example: 
A file offset value shall be divided by 2 or 4 and kept in a uint64_t variable.
So the value range shall be reduced reasonably.

While reading the data, take the uint64_t variable value and multiply by 2 or 4 (Used earlier) and get the exact offset value.