# Union - Binary to Double

Tags: c, binary, unions, low-level

Hello guys I am trying to implement the new frexp function by hand. To be able to do this I used Union data type. I can find the exponent correctly but my problem is about the mantis part. I cannot find the correct value for mantisa part. It gives me really big number but when . I tried to shift the binary but it also didn't help me. Do you have any idea how I can find the mantis from this binary. Thank you. (This is for double floating unit and I assumed double is 64 bit)

P.s. There is one more thing I didn't get. To be able to find the right exponent value, I suppose to decrease that value 1023 in theory (bias property), but in this example I needed to decrease 1022 to find the right value. Is something wrong?

```
typedef union {
    double f;
    struct {
        unsigned long  mantisa : 52;
        unsigned long  exponent : 11;
        unsigned long  sign : 1;
    } parts;
} double_cast;

double myfrexp(double number, int *exp)
{
    double_cast d1;
    d1.f = number;
    unsigned long dd;
    printf("\n %x \n", d1.parts.exponent);
    *exp = d1.parts.exponent - 1022;
    printf("\n%d\n\n", *exp);
    printf("\n %lf \n", (double)d1.parts.mantisa);
    return d1.parts.mantisa;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: what exactly do you expect to get when you print the mantissa? Mantissa bits just represent the fractional part and have an implicit leading `1` in the integer part.

Comment: What compiler are you using?, I'm having trouble compiling your example.

Comment: @self. I am using gcc.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I am trying to convert that values to double. I mean I need the double representation of mantisa.

Comment: Apparently unsigned long bitfields are an extension.

Comment: What do you mean by saying extension? and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Don't use a `struct`.  Use a union of `double` and (`unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`).

Comment: spoiler: code here: https://github.com/xboot/xboot/blob/master/src/lib/libm/frexp.c

Comment: You _might_ do better with `unsigned long  long mantisa : 52;`.

Comment: bitfields are very bad, never use them.  And understand this is not a supported use of a union, that is not what unions are for.  So far I have not seen using a union like this fail to work, but understand the compiler doesnt have to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lessen endian-ness issues and inability to have 52 bit `int` fields, use a union of `double` and `uint64_t`.

It is an assumption that `double` endian-ness and integer endian-ness are the same.  Most systems do that - but not all.  The following depends on that.

The +1 in your post and `expo + 1` below is because 1.0 <= IEEE Significand (not mantissa) < 2.0, but `frexp()`: 0.5 <= normalized fraction < 1.0.

```
double myfrexp(double number, int *exp) {
  static const uint64_t mantissa_mask       = 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFllu;
  static const uint64_t mantissa_impliedBit = 0x0010000000000000llu;
  static const uint64_t expo_mask           = 0x7FF0000000000000llu;
  static const uint64_t expo_norm           = 0x3FE0000000000000llu;
  static const uint64_t sign_mask           = 0x8000000000000000llu;
  static const int expo_NaN = 0x07FF;
  static const int expo_Bias = 1023;

  union {
    double d;
    uint64_t u;
  } x = { number };
  uint64_t mantissa = x.u & mantissa_mask;
  int expo = (x.u & expo_mask) >> 52;

  if (expo == expo_NaN) {  // Behavior for Infinity and NaN is unspecified.
    *exp = 0;
    return number;
  }
  if (expo > 0) {
    mantissa |= mantissa_impliedBit;  // This line is illustrative, not needed.
    expo -= expo_Bias;
  }
  else if (mantissa == 0) {
    *exp = 0;
    return number;  // Do not return 0.0 as that does not preserve -0.0
  }
  else {
    // de-normal or sub-normal numbers
    expo = 1 - expo_Bias;  // Bias different when biased exponent is 0
    while (mantissa < mantissa_impliedBit) {
      mantissa <<= 1;
      expo--;
    }
  }
  *exp = expo + 1;
  mantissa &= ~mantissa_impliedBit;
  x.u = (x.u & sign_mask) | expo_norm | mantissa;
  return x.d;
}

#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

void frexp_test(double d) {
  int i1,i2;
  double d1,d2;
  d1 = frexp(d, &i1);
  d2 = myfrexp(d, &i2);
  if (memcmp(&d1,&d2,sizeof(d1)) != 0 || (i1 != i2)) {
    printf("%a  (%a %x) (%a %x)\n", d, d1, i1, d2, i2);
  }
}

int main() {
  frexp_test(1.0);
  frexp_test(0.0);
  frexp_test(-0.0);
  frexp_test(DBL_MAX);
  frexp_test(-DBL_MAX);
  frexp_test(DBL_EPSILON);
  frexp_test(DBL_MIN);
  frexp_test(DBL_MIN/1024);
  frexp_test(DBL_MIN/1024/1024);
  frexp_test(INFINITY);
  //frexp_test(DBL_TRUE_MIN);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont remember the exact details of IEEE floating-point numbers but I do seem to remember, that the consecutive members of a struct are placed at increasing adresses. What this means is, that your layout seems to assume the mantissa is stored at the lowest address. I think such concerns would go away, if you cast the address of the double variable to a 64bit integer pointer, and use shifts & masks exclusively.

Like so:

```
uint64_t bits = *((uint64_t*)&number);
uint64_t mantissa = bits & ((1<<52)-1);
unsigned exponent = (bits>>52) & 0x7FF;
unsigned sign = bits>>63;
```

To print the results, you could do (ignoring 0.0f, NaN etc):

```
printf("%c1.%"PRIu64"e%u", sign?'-':'+', mantissa, exponent);
```

For using PRIu64 look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132399/how-to-printf-uint64-t)

Comment: I also saw this solution while I was reading for the document. The problem is how I am going to represent mantisa value as a double. I want to be able to write to screen as a double (Just mantisa). My code is basically doing the same thing. and one thing why do I need to "& ~" operation with bits.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to represent the mantissa as a double? The mantissa is an integer I belive, and ought to be printable as such.

Comment: @S-C-Madsen I tried to write mantissa value for my original code, I got 2199023256064 as mantissa for input -18.5623. For the above code I got 0.

Comment: @S-C-Madsen My problem is it gives me 721223332825714 as a mantissa value. I am implementing frexp function and it suppose to be different.

Comment: @Güngör Basa: The error may be the mantissa extraction-code, or your printing routine. I'm pretty sure the mantissa extraction shown should work...