# Printing 64 bit prime sums

Tags: c, printf, primes

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,k=1;
    int i,j;
    unsigned long long int sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=2;i<n;i++){
        for(j=2;j<=i;j++){
            if(i%j==0)
                k++;
        }
        if(k==2){
            sum=sum+i;
        }
        k=1;
    }
    printf("%lld",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is working fine for input `1000,10000` but not for `100000,1000000`, I mean it prints nothing. 
I have also tried `%I64d` but no use.
How can I print `sum` ?

Comment: You want `%llu` for *unsigned*

Comment: It might just take a long time to execute. Are you sure the program finishes executing?

Comment: Works for me. Are you leaving it long enough to run? Or can you find a better algorithm to identify primes? This one is fairly brute-force and slow, and doesn't e.g. abort scanning for a given number as soon as it knows it can't be a prime.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: The statement "prints nothing" implies that you have no idea about debugging your program, you just run it and expect to see results. Please make sure that the call to `printf` is actually executed before deciding that it "prints nothing".

Comment: What's the size of an `int` on your platform? If it happens to be 16 bits, then things may fail when you try to read your input and store that into `n` (in this case, the last 2 numbers).

Comment: Related to the title of the question (which seems to not reflect the actual OP's issue): http://stackoverflow.com/q/8132399/3194340

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you print the sum at each iteration instead of just at the end, so you can see the progress of the computation. Besides being easier to debug your `printf` statement, you can then also detect a possible wrap around (if unsigned long long is not enough for the sum, for example).

Anyway -- I think your question is actually related to your `printf` format string: use `%llu` instead of `%lld`. See the code below:

```
int main(){
    int n,k=1;
    int i,j;
    unsigned long long int sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=2;i<n;i++){
        for(j=2;j<=i;j++){
            if(i%j==0)
                k++;
        }
        if(k==2){
            sum=sum+i;
        }
        k=1;
        /* This helps you see what's going on: */
        printf("sum is %llu\n",sum);
    }
    printf("%llu",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I have used `%llu` instead of `%lld`, and it works fine. If I change it back to `%lld`, nothing is printed on each iteration.

And see that your input (`n`) may not exceed the maximum size of `int` on your platform. (But the sum may be larger, since you declared it as `unsigned long long`).

Also, when checking for primes, you can do some basic optimizations:

- The only even number you need to check is 2. All other primes are odd.
- You don't need to check farther than up to the square root of n. Or, equivalently: suppose you are testing if k divides n. If `n/k<k` (or if `k*k>n`), you may stop testing.

Also, you may use the standard boolean type that is available in C.

See the comments in the code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
/* stdbool defines the type "bool", which can be "true" or "false": */
#include<stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    int i,j;

    /* prime is initialized to true, since we presume every number is prime
       until we find a divisor for it */
    bool prime = true;

    /* sum is initialized to zero. */
    unsigned long long int sum=0;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    /* If n=2, the result is zero. But if it's greater than two, we need
       to count 2 and start searching from 3. It's easier this way, because then
       we can use i=i+2 in the for loop. */
    if (n>2)
        sum = 2;

    /* no need to count from 2. We start from 3 and count every two numbers. */           
    for(i=3;i<n;i=i+2){
        /* same here. And, since this is the divisor we're looking for, we only 
           need to go up to sqrt(i). We use the long casting here because checking
           j*j<=i would not fit in an int type if j^2 is greater than the maximum
           int. This is a corner case, that happens for example when i is maxint
           (j-1)^2 is below and and j^2 is above it. */
        for(j=3;(long)j*j<=i;j=j+2)
            if(i%j==0) {
                prime = false;
                /* get out, since we already know that this one is composite! */
                break;
            }

        /* no divisors? add it to sum! */
        if (prime)
            sum = sum + i;

        /* reset prime to true, we'll start again with next i */
        prime = true;

        printf("sum is %llu\n",sum);
    }
    printf("%llu\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

These are the reasonably simple optimizations that you can do. There are others, and if you are interested, you can study the [sieve of Erathostenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or (if you are math inclined), the [Miller-Rabin test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) (which is not deterministic, but may be of interest). The C library [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) has Miller-Rabin available if you want to use it.

Comment: Minor: `ceill(sqrt(i))` (spelling ? `ceil()`) should be calculated before the `for(j...)` loop rather than each time in the loop.

Comment: chux: right, it is being calculated every time. Will fix it in the answer. But I really meant `ceill`, which returns long. Thinking of it again, since i is int, there is no need to use `ceill`. Thanks!

Comment: Given that `double` typically can not represent every `long long x`, and `double y = sqrt(x)`, the `y` calculated _may_ be too small even when mathematically `y*y == x` exactly.  Your `ceill()` or `ceil()` is a good step but I am not confident either are sufficient.  With systems that calculate the remainder and quotient with little extra performance cost, checking when the quotient is less than `j` is an alternate end-loop condition that does not touch FP math.

Comment: Further speed-up, add `break`. `if(i%j==0) { prime = false; break; }`.  Ahh, but I now see your "There are others...".    +1 for a generally good approach.