# How to print uint64_t in android?

Tags: android, c

According to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132399/how-to-printf-uint64-t), i tried to do it as following:

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

#define TAG "mylog"
#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

uint64_t value = 9999999999;
LOGD("test print uint64_t: %" PRIu64 "\n", value);
```

However, i got the errors as following:

```
error: expected ')' before 'PRIu64'
LOGD("test print uint64_t: %" PRIu64 "\n", value);
```

How to print the uint64_t in Android?

Comment: Did you include stdint.h?

Comment: @Lundin: `PRIu64` is defined in `inttypes.h` (which btw includes `stdint.h`).

Comment: @Michael Aha, didn't know inttypes was required to include stdint.

Comment: Then the next thing to check is adding this macro: `#if !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || (__STDC_VERSION__ < 199901)
#error Your compiler was made by dinosaurs.
#endif`

Comment: @Lundin still compile error after include stdint.h

Comment: Yes, according to the comments above, you don't need to do that, given that you include inttypes.h. So the question is what compiler you are using, does it support C99/C11 and if so, is it set to compile the code as C99/C11?