# Format specifier to portably print std::uint64_t variable in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, printf, portability

What is the format specifier to print a value of type `std::uint64_t` (from `<cstdint>`) using functions from the `std::printf()` family in C++?

C99 has `PRIu64` (from `<inttypes.h>`) but it's not entirely clear to me that `PRIu64` is valid C++11, although I could find hints that it may be.

Without `PRIu64`, and as far as I can tell, there's no single format specifier that will work in all cases:

- On 32-bit platforms, `std::uint64_t` is going to be defined as `unsigned long long` and the format specifier will be `%llu`.
- On 64-bit platforms, `std::uint64_t` is going to be defined as `unsigned long` and the format specifier will be `%lu`.
- However with Visual Studio, `%llu` works in both cases.

Comment: *On 64-bit platforms, std::uint64_t is going to be defined as unsigned long and the format specifier will be %lu.* that is only true for *nix systems.  Windows still uses a 32 bit long in 64 bit systems.

Comment: `<cinttypes>` should have that macro too if I'm not mistaken. Edit: And [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes) verifies it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed, because Windows is LLP64, hence why `%llu` is always the right specifier with Visual Studio.

Comment: @rustyx I'm posting this question precisely because `%llu` doesn't always work.

Comment: Possibly relevant, and maybe even dupe:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132399/how-to-printf-uint64-t-fails-with-spurious-trailing-in-format

Comment: @AndrewHenle Somewhat related but clearly not dupe. Also, this question is specifically about C++11 while the one you linked is about C99. There are many subtle differences between the two when it comes to this topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`PRIu64` is still what you will use in C++.  Per [[cinttypes.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/cinttypes.syn) `PRIu64`

> [...]
>
> ```
> #define PRIuN see below
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The contents and meaning of the header `<cinttypes>` are the same as the C standard library header `<inttypes.h>` [...]

So it exists and has the same behavior that it does in the C ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard.